# Overriding a static method in python

Tags: python, static, overriding

Referring to the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static/114267#114267) about python's bound and unbound methods here, I have a question:

```
class Test:
    def method_one(self):
        print "Called method_one"
    @staticmethod
    def method_two():
        print "Called method_two"
    @staticmethod
    def method_three():
        Test.method_two()
class T2(Test):
    @staticmethod
    def method_two():
        print "T2"
a_test = Test()
a_test.method_one()
a_test.method_two()
a_test.method_three()
b_test = T2()
b_test.method_three()
```

produces output:

```
Called method_one
Called method_two
Called method_two
Called method_two
```

Is there a way to override a static method in python?

I expected `b_test.method_three()` to print "T2", but it doesn't (prints "Called method_two" instead).

Comment: It would work if you put `self.method_two()` instead of `Test.method_two()`. And this should be the correct answer of the question.

Comment: @seahawk `self` is not defined inside a static or class method.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

In the form that you are using there, you are explicitly specifying what class's static `method_two` to call.  If `method_three` was a classmethod, and you called `cls.method_two`, you would get the results that you wanted:

```
class Test:
    def method_one(self):
        print "Called method_one"
    @staticmethod
    def method_two():
        print "Called method_two"
    @classmethod
    def method_three(cls):
        cls.method_two()

class T2(Test):
    @staticmethod
    def method_two():
        print "T2"

a_test = Test()
a_test.method_one()  # -> Called method_one
a_test.method_two()  # -> Called method_two
a_test.method_three()  # -> Called method_two

b_test = T2()
b_test.method_three()  # -> T2
Test.method_two()  # -> Called method_two
T2.method_three()  # -> T2
```

Comment: Really useful. In my case, I needed to access an instance's class. I did it like this: `instance.__class__.my_method()`

Answer (score 3):

The behavior you see is the expected behavior. Static methods are... static. When you call `method_three()` defined in `Test` it will certainly call `method_two()` defined by `Test`.

As for how to "get around" this proper behavior...

The very best way is to make methods virtual when you want virtual behavior. If you're stuck with some library code with a static method that you wish were virtual then you might look deeper to see if there's a reason or if it's just an oversight.

Otherwise, you can define a new `method_three()` in `T2` that calls `T2.method_two()`.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, if you want to call the "virtual static" function without an instance, you could proceed like so:

1. Declare the function in the base class non-static like so:

   ```
   class Base:
       def my_fun(self):
           print('my_fun base')

   class Derived(Base):
       def my_fun(self):
           print('my_fun derived')
   ```
2. Call it by passing the class type, which is not an instance, like so:

   ```
   Derived.my_fun(Derived)
   ```

Note, this is useful if you have a variable "class_type", which is only known during run time.

Comment: At that point, why not just make it a class method? Then it can be overridden and still called statically (no need to pass the class parameter).