# Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?

Tags: java, static, overriding, static-methods

Why is it not possible to override static methods?

If possible, please use an example.

Comment: Most OOP languages don't allow this.

Comment: @jmucchiello: see my answer. I was thinking the same as you, but then learned about Ruby/Smalltalk 'class' methods and so there are other true OOP languages that do this.

Comment: @jmucchiello most OOP language are not real OOP language (I think of Smalltalk)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/370962/632951

Comment: Python allows overriding of a static method.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893015/overriding-a-static-method-in-python

Comment: may be because Java resolves calls to static methods at compile time. So even if you have written `Parent p = new Child()` and then `p.childOverriddenStaticMethod()` the compiler will resolve it to `Parent.childOverriddenStaticMethod()` by looking at the reference type.

Comment: Huzzah, we can now write stuff like http://hastebin.com/codajahati.java. Using such pattern(preferably with less clumsy code), java can eliminate essentially all  exceptions from core library(can, not will), or we can just wrap things.

Answer (score 521, accepted):

Overriding depends on having an instance of a class. The point of polymorphism is that you can subclass a class and the objects implementing those subclasses will have different behaviors for the same methods defined in the superclass (and overridden in the subclasses). A static method is not associated with any instance of a class so the concept is not applicable.

There were two considerations driving Java's design that impacted this. One was a concern with performance: there had been a lot of criticism of Smalltalk about it being too slow (garbage collection and polymorphic calls being part of that) and Java's creators were determined to avoid that. Another was the decision that the target audience for Java was C++ developers. Making static methods work the way they do had the benefit of familiarity for C++ programmers and was also very fast, because there's no need to wait until runtime to figure out which method to call.

Comment: ...but only "correct" in Java. For instance, Scala's equivalent of "static classes" (which are called `objects`) allow overloading of methods.

Comment: Objective-C also allows **overriding** class methods.

Comment: There is a compile-time type hierarchy and a run-time type hierarchy.  It makes perfect sense to ask why a static method call doesn't avail itself of the run-time type hierarchy in those circumstances where there is one.  In Java this happens when calling a static method from an object (`obj.staticMethod()`) -- which is allowed and uses the compile-time types.  When the static call is in a non-static method of a class, the "current" object could be a derived type of the class -- but static methods defined on the derived types are not considered (they are in the run-time type hierarchy).

Comment: I should have made it clear: it is _not_ true that *the concept is not applicable*.

Comment: I think this answer doesn't answer the question -- which was "Why not?"  The reasons why are obscure, and it is not at all the case that the concept wouldn't work in Java.

Comment: @Steve: by "the concept is not applicable" i meant, it's not helpful to try to think about static methods in terms of OO or class methods. as to *why*, it's one of those performance hacks, like having primitive types, where Java's creators were trying to avoid a rep for being slow like Smalltalk had at the time. would it help to modify the answer along those lines?

Comment: @user166390 scala's objects are not an equivalent of java "static classes". They are more the equivalent of what can be achieved in java with singleton or factory (but without all the boilerplate that these pattern require in Java). Note that you would be able to create equivalent code in java without static methods, except that it would be many times more verbose.

Comment: This answer, while correct, is more akin to "how it is" rather than how it should be or more accurately how it could be in order to meet the expectations of the OP and, hence here, myself and others. There is no concrete reason to disallow the overriding of static methods other than "that's how it is". I think it's a flaw personally.

Comment: @NathanHughes, This is a followup question: From your answer and others below, it seems that the reason why one cannot "override" a static method hinges upon the definition of the word "override," in Java. Because "override" means "change the behavior based upon the actual object datatype regardless of the reference datatype" and static methods, by definition, do NOT change the behavior from that in the reference datatype then one cannot SAY a static method with a matching signature in a subtype is overriding the supertype method. Thus, we SAY it is "hiding" the supertype method.

Comment: Here is a followup to the above followup question: Assuming that my supposition above is correct, does that mean what people are really asking for is that there be a way for class methods to change their behavior dynamically based upon the datatype of the actual object? It does seem to me that this is working at cross-purposes. If one wants the behavior to change dynamically based upon the actual objects, then that means there WILL be objects upon which to call the method. So what would be the point of making said method a class method?

Comment: @GrantR: yes, there's an expectation people have that class methods work dynamically similar to smalltalk/ruby/python etc. here's an example for python at https://julien.danjou.info/blog/2013/guide-python-static-class-abstract-methods

Comment: PHP 5.3+ have special way of override static method too - late static binding. But most PHP developers are not familiar with this feature anyway.

Comment: `"A static method is not associated with any instance of a class so the concept is not applicable."`. Nonsense, it is associated with the class itself, so it would make sense to have IBox have method "public static IBox createBox" which is overriden by "Box" object that implemented "IBox". Without this, we are forced to create "unnatural" factory classes, or resort to failing in constructors(as we cannot have static method return the object, and rely on constructor, which cannot return null, which promoted unnecessary exceptions). if Box could override createBox, it could eliminate all this.

Comment: Re:  "there had been a lot of criticism of Smalltalk about it being too slow".  Note: Smalltalk ran on a 286 (1M of RAM). The garbage collection was slow on a 286 and first impressions stuck.  Here's a reference from 1995 suggesting Smalltalk and C++ had similar performance for applications. http://www.jeffsutherland.org/papers/oocobol.html

Comment: @slaman: there was criticism, I never said it was well-founded.

Answer (score 200):

Personally I think this is a flaw in the design of Java. Yes, yes, I understand that non-static methods are attached to an instance while static methods are attached to a class, etc etc. Still, consider the following code:

```
public class RegularEmployee {
    private BigDecimal salary;

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public static BigDecimal getBonusMultiplier() {
        return new BigDecimal(".02");
    }

    public BigDecimal calculateBonus() {
        return salary.multiply(getBonusMultiplier());
    }

    /* ... presumably lots of other code ... */
}

public class SpecialEmployee extends RegularEmployee {
    public static BigDecimal getBonusMultiplier() {
        return new BigDecimal(".03");
    }
}
```

This code will not work as you might expect. Namely, SpecialEmployee's get a 2% bonus just like regular employees. But if you remove the "static"s, then SpecialEmployee's get a 3% bonus.

(Admittedly, this example is poor coding style in that in real life you would likely want the bonus multiplier to be in a database somewhere rather than hard-coded. But that's just because I didn't want to bog down the example with a lot of code irrelevant to the point.)

It seems quite plausible to me that you might want to make getBonusMultiplier static. Perhaps you want to be able to display the bonus multiplier for all the categories of employees, without needing to have an instance of an employee in each category. What would be the point of searching for such example instances? What if we are creating a new category of employee and don't have any employees assigned to it yet? This is quite logically a static function.

But it doesn't work.

And yes, yes, I can think of any number of ways to rewrite the above code to make it work. My point is not that it creates an unsolvable problem, but that it creates a trap for the unwary programmer, because the language does not behave as I think a reasonable person would expect.

Perhaps if I tried to write a compiler for an OOP language, I would quickly see why implementing it so that static functions can be overriden would be difficult or impossible.

Or perhaps there is some good reason why Java behaves this way. Can anyone point out an advantage to this behavior, some category of problem that is made easier by this? I mean, don't just point me to the Java language spec and say "see, this is documented how it behaves". I know that. But is there a good reason why it SHOULD behave this way? (Besides the obvious "making it work right was too hard"...)

**Update**

@VicKirk: If you mean that this is "bad design" because it doesn't fit how Java handles statics, my reply is, "Well, duh, of course." As I said in my original post, it doesn't work. But if you mean that it is bad design in the sense that there would be something fundamentally wrong with a language where this worked, i.e. where statics could be overridden just like virtual functions, that this would somehow introduce an ambiguity or it would be impossible to implement efficiently or some such, I reply, "Why? What's wrong with the concept?"

I think the example I give is a very natural thing to want to do. I have a class that has a function that does not depend on any instance data, and which I might very reasonably want to call independent of an instance, as well as wanting to call from within an instance method. Why should this not work? I've run into this situation a fair number of times over the years. In practice I get around it by making the function virtual, and then creating a static method whose only purpose in life is to be a static method that passes the call on to the virtual method with a dummy instance. That seems like a very roundabout way to get there.

Comment: Although this code works in Java, it's a quirk of Java, which lets you call static methods on an instance.  It would fail in C#, because C# doesn't allow you to call static methods as an instance method like you're doing on the `salary.multiply` line.

Comment: This example is just a bad design and does not highlight any 'flaw' with the implementation of static methods.  I can't think of any example where I would want to override them, would you really want to write code like  bonus = (obj instanceof B) ?  B.bonus() : A.bonus().  What if it was overridden on type C, or a third party adds type D, every bit of code that uses the methods is then broken.  True you could write the above with an instance variable but then it would be an instance method, as it then requires an instance to resolve the method!

Comment: BTW, as things are instance.staticMethod()  is likely to be optimised with IntanceClass.staticMethod()

Comment: Class are not first-class entity in java. You can call a static method with `obj.staticMethod()` or `staticMethod()` but the compiler treats that as `MyClass.staticMethod()` depending on the scope it is compiled. You should always use `MyClass.staticMethod()` to avoid the confusion that you just described. See my answer which I refined.

Comment: @Bemrose: But that's my point: Why shouldn't I be allowed to do that? Maybe my intuitive concept of what a "static" should do is different from yours, but basically I think of a static as a method that CAN be static because it doesn't use any instance data, and which SHOULD be static because you may want to call it independently of an instance. A static is clearly tied to a class: I expect Integer.valueOf to be tied to Integers and Double.valueOf to be tied to Doubles.

Comment: @Jay:  Honestly, you shouldn't.  I don't know why the developers of Java decided to do it that way.  It's basically a compiler trick, as vickirk implied.

Comment: @ewernli & Bemrose: Yes yes, that's how it IS. I'm not debating that. As the code in my example doesn't work, of course I wouldn't try to write it. My question is why it is that way. (I fear this is turning into one of those conversations where we're just not communicating. "Excuse me Mr Salesman, can I get one of these in red?" "No, it costs $5." "Yes, I know it costs $5, but can I get a red one?" "Sir, I just told you that it costs $5." "Okay, I know the price, but I was asking about the color." "I already told you the price!" etc.)

Comment: Jay, regarding your last comment, it would make much more sense to have the instance method call the static method and have the implementation in the static method. Why create an instance when you don't need one?

Comment: I think that ultimately this code is confusing. Consider if the instance is passed as a parameter. Then you are saying that the runtime instance should dictate which static method is called. That basically makes a whole separate hierarchy parallel to the existing instance one. Now what if a subclass defines the same method signature as non-static? I think that the rules would make things quite complicated. It is precisely these kinds of language complications that Java tries to avoid.

Comment: @Yishai: RE "Runtime instance dictate which static method is called": Exactly. I don't see why you can't do anything with a static that you can do with a virtual. "Separate hierarchy": I'd say, Make it part of the same hierarchy. Why aren't statics included in the same hierarchy? "Subsclass defines the same signature non-static": I presume that would be illegal, just like it's illegal to, say, have a subclass override a function with an identical signature but a different return type, or to not throw all the exceptions that the parent throws, or to have a narrower scope.

Comment: I put the real logic in a virtual and create a static to call it with a dummy object, rather than putting the real logic in a virtual, because the whole point is that I need to override the logic in a subclass, and Java doesn't allow me to override a static.

Comment: "I think the example I give is a very natural thing to want to do. I have a class that has a function that does not depend on any instance data" - but it depends on what type the instance of an object is.  How could you possibly call the correct method if you don't know what type of object it is, polymorphism is not driven by object state, rather than the behavior an instance exhibits.

Comment: If I want to call a static function without having an instance, then yes, of course I have to specify the class. It seems very natural to me that I should be able to call a static function via a class name and either a static or virtual function via an object instance. Why not?

Comment: PS I don't want to circle around an argument forever. If we disagree, at some point we have to just say, "Okay, we disagree and neither is about to convince the other." But if you two want to continue to trade comments, I'm game.

Comment: But surely if you need an instance of an object to resolve which static method to call it is just not a static method.   "Okay, we disagree and neither is about to convince the other." - I'm going to leave it at that :-)

Comment: I think Jay has a point - it surprised me too when I discovered that statics could not be overridden.  In part because if I have A with method `someStatic()` and B extends A, then `B.someMethod()` *binds* to the method in A.  If I subsequently add `someStatic()` to B, the calling code still invokes `A.someStatic()` until I recompile the calling code. Also it surprised me that `bInstance.someStatic()` uses the *declared* type of bInstance, not the runtime type because it binds at compile not link, so `A bInstance; ... bInstance.someStatic()` invokes A.someStatic() if if B.someStatic() exists.

Comment: But ultimately, I find myself agreeing with vickirk: "surely if you need an instance of an object to resolve which static method to call it is just not a static method".  I wish Java had never allowed static invocation via an instance reference, and I wish that they would now add a compiler lint switch to issue a warning for it.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: I don't think it's inherently unreasonable to say that you CAN USE an instance to decide which static method to call. Yes, if you MUST HAVE an instance, then it's not a static any more. But to say that the compiler could examine the instance, see what class it is, and then use that to decide which static function ... seems quite reasonable to me. Again, see my example that started this argument ... I mean thread.

Comment: @Jay: That's the problem - the compiler can't examine the "instance" to see what it is, since the instance doesn't exist until runtime.  The compiler can only invoke the static method based on the declared type, which could be the actual type or any of its super classes.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: We're back to "is" versus "should be". Yes, what you are saying is how Java is. I'm not disputing that. But I see no reason why it couldn't choose a static method based on the runtime type, just as it chooses a virtual method based on the runtime type. Why couldn't static methods be included in the pointer table along with the virtual methods? Yes, this would mean there would be two ways to get to them. But so what?

Comment: @Jay I would propose that `obj.staticMethod()` uses the run-time type hierarchy but that plain `staticMethod()` (in a class method) uses the compile-time type hierarchy.  This means that your example would *not* work, unless you changed it to `this.staticMethod()`. Notice that `this` has the run-time type that you want to use.

Comment: What's flawed in your example is your motivation for wanting to make `getBonusMultiplier()` static. The thing that it makes sense to have static and not per-instance copies of proliferating is the multiplier itself. What makes more sense is for each class to have constants for this, as in `static final BigDecimal multiplier = new BigDecimal(".03");` Then a non-static `getBonusMultiplier()` method in each class can use the static multiplier from that class.

Comment: Well, okay, I was trying to create a simple example, and yes, in this case you could solve the problem by creating a variable to hold the multiplier. But surely it's not hard to imagine real-world cases that are not that simple. Like, for salesman the bonus is based on their sales for the quarter, for managers it's based on revenue for their division, and for clerical people it's a percentage of their salary. The point is whether there is a way to accomplish this particular example, but whether there is a way to accomplish the idea in general, in more complex real-world cases.

Comment: Didn't read the 69 previous comments but I wholeheartedly give you a +1 - _yes - wanting to override a static method is a **quite valid** requirement oftentimes_. The problem is not unexperienced programmers btw - is mainly experienced ones - frustrated by the unability to define common behavior for all subclasses easily and elegantly - "the benefit of familiarity for C++ programmers", duh

Comment: @LawrenceDol, @StevePowell, That's not a problem because the compiler doesn't need to examine the instance at all. If `parent.StaticMethod` returns type `C1`, then `child.StaticMethod` is required to return an object of type `C1` or subtype of `C1`. So the compiler knows for sure that the returned type is of (sub)type `C1` and due to Liskov substitution principle there's no conflicts. Why do you say that there is a problem?

Comment: @Jay if you replace `return salary.multiply(getBonusMultiplier());` with 
`try {
    Method m = this.getClass().getMethod("getBonusMultiplier");
    return  salary.multiply((BigDecimal) m.invoke(null));
} catch (NoSuchMethodException
           | SecurityException
           | IllegalAccessException
           | IllegalArgumentException
           | InvocationTargetException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Parent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}` it does work. Makes me wonder: why does Java not support implicit reflection: `return salary.multiply(origin.getBonusMultiplier());`

Comment: Introduce some feature (especially when it makes reading the code more tricky but gives more power) in Scala and nobody bats an eye. Ask why it's not in Java and suddenly everybody loses their mind, telling you what a bad design that would be.

Comment: @Jay When `RegularEmployee` instance call `getBonusMultiplier()`, it get `0.3`, not `0.2`, refer: https://ideone.com/fqmuks

Comment: @Lawrence Dol: if you write `B.someMethod()` in your source code, the compiled code will refer `B.someMethod()`, not `A.someMethod()`, even if the method happened to be found in the super class `A`, so adding the method to `B` afterwards *will* cause the already compiled code to use `B.someMethod()` without the need to recompile. It seems to be a tenacious myth of `static` methods being bound at compile-time but they are bound at *load-time* (or *link-time*, if the JVM makes a difference between the two). There were compilers in the past (1.2 or earlier) which did it wrong, but that’s long ago

Comment: @Holger Yes, true. But A b=new B(); b.someMethod(); executes A.someMethod, even though b is a B. That's the point under discussion.

Comment: @Jay: Well, Lawrence referred to both scenarios and for the case that the source code refers to `B.someMethod();`, his statement had to be corrected. The case of writing `instance.staticMethod()` has already been widely discussed; I tend to say that the possibility to write it that way shouldn’t have existed in the first place, however, I don’t want to reopen that discussion.

Comment: If you intend to override a method without using the @Override annotation, then you deserve all the problems that come your way because of it.  It's a bad practice.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be `valueOf(String s)`. I can imagine some interface "`CanGetValueOfString`" that would prescribe such a static method, to be implemented by the likes of `Integer` and `Double` and so on.

Answer (score 45):

The short answer is: it is entirely possible, but Java doesn't do it.

Here is some code which illustrates the ***current state of affairs*** in Java:

File `Base.java`:

```
package sp.trial;
public class Base {
  static void printValue() {
    System.out.println("  Called static Base method.");
  }
  void nonStatPrintValue() {
    System.out.println("  Called non-static Base method.");
  }
  void nonLocalIndirectStatMethod() {
    System.out.println("  Non-static calls overridden(?) static:");
    System.out.print("  ");
    this.printValue();
  }
}
```

File `Child.java`:

```
package sp.trial;
public class Child extends Base {
  static void printValue() {
    System.out.println("  Called static Child method.");
  }
  void nonStatPrintValue() {
    System.out.println("  Called non-static Child method.");
  }
  void localIndirectStatMethod() {
    System.out.println("  Non-static calls own static:");
    System.out.print("  ");
    printValue();
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Object: static type Base; runtime type Child:");
    Base base = new Child();
    base.printValue();
    base.nonStatPrintValue();
    System.out.println("Object: static type Child; runtime type Child:");
    Child child = new Child();
    child.printValue();
    child.nonStatPrintValue();
    System.out.println("Class: Child static call:");
    Child.printValue();
    System.out.println("Class: Base static call:");
    Base.printValue();
    System.out.println("Object: static/runtime type Child -- call static from non-static method of Child:");
    child.localIndirectStatMethod();
    System.out.println("Object: static/runtime type Child -- call static from non-static method of Base:");
    child.nonLocalIndirectStatMethod();
  }
}
```

If you run this (I did it on a Mac, from Eclipse, using Java 1.6) you get:

```
Object: static type Base; runtime type Child.
  Called static Base method.
  Called non-static Child method.
Object: static type Child; runtime type Child.
  Called static Child method.
  Called non-static Child method.
Class: Child static call.
  Called static Child method.
Class: Base static call.
  Called static Base method.
Object: static/runtime type Child -- call static from non-static method of Child.
  Non-static calls own static.
    Called static Child method.
Object: static/runtime type Child -- call static from non-static method of Base.
  Non-static calls overridden(?) static.
    Called static Base method.
```

Here, the *only* cases which might be a surprise (and which the question is about) appear to be the *first* case:

"The run-time type is not used to determine which static methods are called, even when called with an object instance (`obj.staticMethod()`)."

and the *last* case:

"When calling a static method from within an object method of a class, the static method chosen is the one accessible from the class itself and *not* from the class defining the run-time type of the object."

#### Calling with an object instance

The static call is resolved at compile-time, whereas a non-static method call is resolved at run-time.  Notice that although static methods are *inherited* (from parent) they are not *overridden* (by child).  This could be a surprise if you expected otherwise.

#### Calling from within an object method

*Object* method calls are resolved using the run-time type, but static (*class*) method calls are resolved using the compile-time (declared) type.

#### Changing the rules

To change these rules, so that the last call in the example called `Child.printValue()`, static calls would have to be provided with a type at run-time, rather than the compiler resolving the call at compile-time with the declared class of the object (or context). Static calls could then use the (dynamic) type hierarchy to resolve the call, just as object method calls do today.

This would easily be doable (if we changed Java :-O), and is not at all unreasonable, however, it has some interesting considerations.

The main consideration is that we need to decide *which* static method calls should do this.

At the moment, Java has this "quirk" in the language whereby `obj.staticMethod()` calls are replaced by `ObjectClass.staticMethod()` calls (normally with a warning). [*Note:* `ObjectClass` is the compile-time type of `obj`.] These would be good candidates for overriding in this way, taking the run-time type of `obj`.

If we did it would make method bodies harder to read: static calls in a parent class could potentially be *dynamically* "re-routed".  To avoid this we would have to call the static method with a class name -- and this makes the calls more obviously resolved with the compile-time type hierarchy (as now).

The other ways of invoking a static method are more tricky: `this.staticMethod()` should mean the same as `obj.staticMethod()`, taking the run-time type of `this`.  However, this might cause some headaches with existing programs, which call (apparently local) static methods without decoration (which is arguably equivalent to `this.method()`).

So what about unadorned calls `staticMethod()`?  I suggest they do the same as today, and use the local class context to decide what to do.  Otherwise great confusion would ensue.  Of course it means that `method()` would mean `this.method()` if `method` was a non-static method, and `ThisClass.method()` if `method` were a static method.  This is another source of confusion.

#### Other considerations

If we changed this behaviour (and made static calls potentially dynamically non-local), we would probably want to revisit the meaning of `final`, `private` and `protected` as qualifiers on `static` methods of a class.  We would then all have to get used to the fact that `private static` and `public final` methods are not overridden, and can therefore be safely resolved at compile-time, and are "safe" to read as local references.

Comment: "If we did it would make method bodies harder to read: static calls in a parent class could potentially be dynamically "re-routed"." True, but this is exactly what happens with ordinary non-static function calls now. This is routinely touted as a positive feature for ordinary virtual functions, not a problem.

Answer (score 26):

Actually we were wrong.
Despite Java doesn't allow you to override static methods by default, if you look thoroughly through documentation of Class and Method classes in Java, you can still find a way to emulate static methods overriding by following workaround:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;

class RegularEmployee {

    private BigDecimal salary = BigDecimal.ONE;

    public void setSalary(BigDecimal salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }
    public static BigDecimal getBonusMultiplier() {
        return new BigDecimal(".02");
    }
    public BigDecimal calculateBonus() {
        return salary.multiply(this.getBonusMultiplier());
    }
    public BigDecimal calculateOverridenBonus() {
        try {
            // System.out.println(this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
            // "getBonusMultiplier").toString());
            try {
                return salary.multiply((BigDecimal) this.getClass()
                    .getDeclaredMethod("getBonusMultiplier").invoke(this));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    // ... presumably lots of other code ...
}

final class SpecialEmployee extends RegularEmployee {

    public static BigDecimal getBonusMultiplier() {
        return new BigDecimal(".03");
    }
}

public class StaticTestCoolMain {

    static public void main(String[] args) {
        RegularEmployee Alan = new RegularEmployee();
        System.out.println(Alan.calculateBonus());
        System.out.println(Alan.calculateOverridenBonus());
        SpecialEmployee Bob = new SpecialEmployee();
        System.out.println(Bob.calculateBonus());
        System.out.println(Bob.calculateOverridenBonus());
    }
}
```

Resulting output:

```
0.02
0.02
0.02
0.03
```

what we were trying to achieve :)

Even if we declare third variable Carl as RegularEmployee and assign to it instance of SpecialEmployee, we will still have call of RegularEmployee method in first case and call of SpecialEmployee method in second case

```
RegularEmployee Carl = new SpecialEmployee();

System.out.println(Carl.calculateBonus());
System.out.println(Carl.calculateOverridenBonus());
```

just look at output console:

```
0.02
0.03
```

;)

Comment: Yes reflection is pretty much the only thing one can do - but the question is not exactly this - useful to have it here though

Comment: This answer is the biggest hack I've seen so far across all Java topics. Was fun to read it still :)

Answer (score 19):

Static methods are treated as global by the JVM, there are not bound to an object instance at all.

It could conceptually be possible if you could call static methods from class objects (like in languages like Smalltalk) but it's not the case in Java.

**EDIT**

You can *overload* static method, that's ok. But you can not *override* a static method, because class are no first-class object. You can use reflection to get the class of an object at run-time, but the object that you get does not parallel the class hierarchy.

```
class MyClass { ... }
class MySubClass extends MyClass { ... }

MyClass obj1 = new MyClass();
MySubClass obj2 = new MySubClass();

ob2 instanceof MyClass --> true

Class clazz1 = obj1.getClass();
Class clazz2 = obj2.getClass();

clazz2 instanceof clazz1 --> false
```

You can reflect over the classes, but it stops there. You don't invoke a static method by using `clazz1.staticMethod()`, but using `MyClass.staticMethod()`. A static method is not bound to an object and there is hence no notion of `this` nor `super` in a static method. A static method is a global function; as a consequence there is also no notion of polymorphism and, therefore, method overriding makes no sense.

But this could be possible if `MyClass` was an object at run-time on which you invoke a method, as in Smalltalk (or maybe JRuby as one comment suggest, but I know nothing of JRuby).

Oh yeah... one more thing. You can invoke a static method through an object `obj1.staticMethod()` but that really syntactic sugar for `MyClass.staticMethod()` and should be avoided. It usually raises a warning in modern IDE. I don't know why they ever allowed this shortcut.

Comment: Even many modern languages like Ruby have class-methods and allow overriding them.

Comment: Classes do exist as objects in Java. See the "Class" class. I can say myObject.getClass() and it will return me an instance of the appropriate class object.

Comment: You get only a "description" of the class -- not the class itself. But the difference is subtle.

Comment: You still have class but it is hidden in the VM (near the class loader), user have almost no access to it.

Comment: To use `clazz2 instanceof clazz1` properly you can instead use `class2.isAssignableFrom(clazz1)`, which I believe would return true in your example.

Answer (score 17):

Method overriding is made possible by [dynamic dispatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch), meaning that the declared type of an object doesn't determine its behavior, but rather its runtime type:

```
Animal lassie = new Dog();
lassie.speak(); // outputs "woof!"
Animal kermit = new Frog();
kermit.speak(); // outputs "ribbit!"
```

Even though both `lassie` and `kermit` are declared as objects of type `Animal`, their behavior (method `.speak()`) varies because dynamic dispatching will only [bind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_binding) the method call `.speak()` to an implementation at run time - not at compile time.

Now, here's where the `static` keyword starts to make sense: **the word "static" is an antonym for "dynamic".** So the reason why you can't override static methods is because there is no dynamic dispatching on static members - **because static literally means "not dynamic".** If they dispatched dynamically (and thus could be overriden) the `static` keyword just wouldn't make sense anymore.

Comment: I don't think, one should argue "static" vs "dynamic" by its internal implementation. That's an language's API keyword. What is the programmer expecting? Static methods return constant results while running (for a specific class) => static. Member functions return results, depending on instance's variables (which can change while running) => dynamic.

Answer (score 14):

Yes. Practically Java allows overriding static method, and No theoretically if you Override a static method in Java then it will compile and run smoothly but it will lose Polymorphism which is the basic property of Java. You will Read Everywhere that it is not possible to try yourself compiling and running. you will get your answer. e.g. If you Have Class Animal and a static method eat() and you Override that static method in its Subclass lets called it Dog. Then when wherever you Assign a Dog object to an Animal Reference and call eat() according to Java Dog's eat() should have been called but in static Overriding Animals' eat() will Be Called.

```
class Animal {
    public static void eat() {
        System.out.println("Animal Eating");
    }
}

class Dog extends Animal{
    public static void eat() {
        System.out.println("Dog Eating");
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       Animal obj= new Dog();//Dog object in animal
       obj.eat(); //should call dog's eat but it didn't
    }
}


Output Animal Eating
```

According to Polymorphism Principle of Java, the Output Should be `Dog Eating`.
But the result was different because to support Polymorphism Java uses Late Binding that means methods are called only at the run-time but not in the case of static methods. In static methods compiler calls methods at the compile time rather than the run-time, so we get methods according to the reference and not according to the object a reference a containing that's why You can say Practically it supports static overring but theoretically, it doesn't.

Comment: It's bad practice to call static methods from object.

Answer (score 7):

In Java (and many OOP languages, but I cannot speak for all; and some do not have static at all) all methods have a fixed signature - the parameters and types. In a virtual method, the first parameter is implied: a reference to the object itself and when called from within the object, the compiler automatically adds `this`.

There is no difference for static methods - they still have a fixed signature. However, by declaring the method static you have explicitly stated that the compiler must not include the implied object parameter at the beginning of that signature. Therefore, any other code that calls this must *must not attempt to put a reference to an object on the stack*. If it did do that, then the method execution would not work since the parameters would be in the wrong place - shifted by one - on the stack.

Because of this difference between the two; virtual methods always have a reference to the context object (i.e. `this`) so then it is possible to reference anything within the heap that belong to that instance of the object. But with static methods, since there is no reference passed, that method cannot access any object variables and methods since the context is not known.

If you wish that Java would change the definition so that a object context is passed in for every method, static or virtual, then you would in essence have only virtual methods.

As someone asked in a comment to the op - what is your reason and purpose for wanting this feature?

I do not know Ruby much, as this was mentioned by the OP, I did some research. I see that in Ruby classes are really a special kind of object and one can create (even dynamically) new methods. Classes are full class objects in Ruby, they are not in Java. This is just something you will have to accept when working with Java (or C#). These are not dynamic languages, though C# is adding some forms of dynamic. In reality, Ruby does not have "static" methods as far as I could find - in that case these are methods on the singleton class object. You can then override this singleton with a new class and the methods in the previous class object will call those defined in the new class (correct?). So if you called a method in the context of the original class it still would only execute the original statics, but calling a method in the derived class, would call methods either from the parent or sub-class. Interesting and I can see some value in that. It takes a different thought pattern.

Since you are working in Java, you will need to adjust to that way of doing things. Why they did this? Well, probably to improve performance at the time based on the technology and understanding that was available. Computer languages are constantly evolving. Go back far enough and there is no such thing as OOP. In the future, there will be other new ideas.

**EDIT**: One other comment. Now that I see the differences and as I Java/C# developer myself, I can understand why the answers you get from Java developers may be confusing if you are coming from a language like Ruby. Java `static` methods are not the same as Ruby `class` methods. Java developers will have a hard time understanding this, as will conversely those who work mostly with a language like Ruby/Smalltalk. I can see how this would also be greatly confusing by the fact that Java also uses "class method" as another way to talk about static methods but this same term is used differently by Ruby. Java does not have Ruby style class methods (sorry); Ruby does not have Java style static methods which are really just old procedural style functions, as found in C.

By the way - thanks for the question! I learned something new for me today about class methods (Ruby style).

Comment: Of course, there's no reason why Java couldn't pass a "Class" object as a hidden parameter to static methods. It just wasn't designed to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Well... the answer is NO if you think from the perspective of how an overriden method should behave in Java. But, you don't get any compiler error if you try to override a static method. That means, if you try to override, Java doesn't stop you doing that; but you certainly don't get the same effect as you get for non-static methods. Overriding in Java simply means that the particular method would be called based on the run time type of the object and not on the compile time type of it (which is the case with overriden static methods). Okay... any guesses for the reason why do they behave strangely? Because they are class methods and hence access to them is always resolved during compile time only using the compile time type information. Accessing them using object references is just an extra liberty given by the designers of Java and we should certainly not think of stopping that practice only when they restrict it :-)

***Example***: let's try to see what happens if we try overriding a static method:-

```
class SuperClass {
// ......
public static void staticMethod() {
    System.out.println("SuperClass: inside staticMethod");
}
// ......
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
// ......
// overriding the static method
public static void staticMethod() {
    System.out.println("SubClass: inside staticMethod");
}

// ......
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // ......
    SuperClass superClassWithSuperCons = new SuperClass();
    SuperClass superClassWithSubCons = new SubClass();
    SubClass subClassWithSubCons = new SubClass();

    superClassWithSuperCons.staticMethod();
    superClassWithSubCons.staticMethod();
    subClassWithSubCons.staticMethod();
    // ...
}
}
```

***Output***:-
`SuperClass: inside staticMethod` 
`SuperClass: inside staticMethod` 
`SubClass: inside staticMethod`

Notice the second line of the output. Had the staticMethod been overriden this line should have been identical to the third line as we're invoking the 'staticMethod()' on an object of Runtime Type as 'SubClass' and not as 'SuperClass'. This confirms that the static methods are always resolved using their compile time type information only.

Answer (score 6):

I like and double Jay's comment (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223803/1517187).
I agree that this is the bad design of Java.
Many other languages support overriding static methods, as we see in previous comments.
I feel Jay has also come to Java from Delphi like me.
Delphi (Object Pascal) was one of the languages implementing OOP before Java and one of the first languages used for commercial application development.
It is obvious that many people had experience with that language since it was in the past the only language to write commercial GUI products. And - yes, we could in Delphi override static methods. Actually, static methods in Delphi are called "class methods", while Delphi had the different concept of "Delphi static methods" which were methods with early binding. To override methods you had to use late binding, declare "virtual" directive. So it was very convenient and intuitive and I would expect this in Java.

Comment: *Delphi (Object Pascal) was the first language implementing OOP.*   Simula, SmallTalk, and others supporting OOP and all came before Delphi.

Comment: @WJS I have never heard about Simula or other languages that supported OOP. I think Delphi was the first language implementing OOP used in commercial application development and wide-known. Looks like I need to rephrase this statement

Answer (score 5):

overriding is reserved for instance members to support polymorphic behaviour. static class members do not belong to a particular instance. instead, static members belong to the class and as a result overriding is not supported because subclasses only inherit protected and public instance members and not static members. You may want to define an inerface and research factory and/or strategy design patterns to evaluate an alternate approach.

Comment: Did you not read any of the other answer already covering this and making it clear that these are not reasons enough to discount overriding statics at the conceptual level. We know it doesnt work. It is perfectly "clean to desire the overriding of static methods and indeed it IS possible in many other languages.

Comment: Richard, let's assume for a minute that when I responded to this question 4 years ago most of these answers had not been posted, so don't be an ass! There is no need to assert that I did not read carefully. Furthermore, did you not read that we are only discussing overriding with respect to Java. Who cares what's possible in other languages. It's irrelevant. Go troll somewhere else. Your comment does not add anything of value to this thread.

Answer (score 5):

In general it doesn't make sense to allow 'overriding' of static methods as there would be no good way to determine which one to call at runtime. Taking the Employee example, if we call RegularEmployee.getBonusMultiplier() - which method is supposed to be executed?

In the case of Java, one could imagine a language definition where it is possible to 'override' static methods as long as they are called through an object instance. However, all this would do is to re-implement regular class methods, adding redundancy to the language without really adding any benefit.

Comment: Intuitively, I would think it should work just like a virtual function. If B extends A and both A and B have virtual functions named doStuff, the compiler knows that instances of A should use A.doStuff and instances of B should use B.doStuff. Why can't it do the same with static functions? After all, the compiler knows what class each object is an instance of.

Comment: Erm ... Jay, a static method need not be (generally is not) called on an instance ...

Comment: @meriton, but then it's even easier, no?  If a static method is called using a classname, you'd use the method appropriate for the class.

Comment: But then what is overriding doing for you.  If you call A.doStuff() should it use the version that was overridden in "B extends A" or the version that was overridden in "C extends A".  And if you have C or B then you are calling those versions anyway... no overriding necessary.

Comment: @meriton: It is true that a static method is generally not called with an instance, but I presume that is because such a call does nothing useful given the current design of Java! I am suggesting that an alternative design might have been a better idea. BTW, in a very real sense static functions are called with an instance quite routinely: When you call the static function from within a virtual function. Then you implicitly get this.function(), i.e. the current instance.

Comment: @Jay: No, that is not true. The compiler will generate a different type of call. For all virtual method calls, the compiler puts a reference to `this` on the stack. With a static method call (even, unfortunately with Java's `this.staticMethod()`) there is no hidden reference so the compiler really strips off `this.` from that call.

Comment: @Kevin: Okay, my statement was poorly worded. I meant that if you call a static function from within the same class, you get the same function that you would get if you wrote "this.function()", i.e. the static in the "current" class, or the first one found as you chase up the hierarchy. (I think that's true: I'll have to check that out.) I did not mean to imply that it turned the call into a virtual call.

Answer (score 5):

By overriding we can create a polymorphic nature depending on the object type. Static method has no relation with object. So java can not support static method overriding.

Answer (score 5):

By overriding, you achieve dynamic polymorphism.
When you say overriding static methods, the words you are trying to use are contradictory.

Static says - compile time, overriding is used for dynamic polymorphism.
Both are opposite in nature, and hence can't be used together.

Dynamic polymorphic behavior comes when a programmer uses an object and accessing an instance method. JRE will map different instance methods of different classes based on what kind of object you are using.

When you say overriding static methods, static methods we will access by using the class name, which will be linked at compile time, so there is no concept of linking methods at runtime with static methods. So the term "overriding" static methods itself doesn't make any meaning.

Note: even if you access a class method with an object, still java compiler is intelligent enough to find it out, and will do static linking.

Comment: This is not true in a lot of instances where at runtime the static method is in fact called from an instance of the containing class and thus it's perfectly feasible to determine which instances of the function to invoke.

Comment: static does not mean compile time, static means that it is bound to class rather then any specific object. it makes as much if not more sense than creating a class factory, except static `Box.createBox` makes more sense than `BoxFactory.createBox`, and is an unavoidable pattern when needing to error check construction without throwing exceptions(constructors can't fail, they can only kill the process/throw exception), whereas a static method can return null on failure, or even accept success/error callbacks to write something like http://hastebin.com/codajahati.java.

Answer (score 3):

Overriding in Java simply means that the particular method would be called based on the runtime type 
of the object and not on the compile-time type of it (which is the case with overridden static methods). As static methods are class methods they are not instance methods so they have nothing to do with the fact which reference is pointing to which Object or instance, because due to the nature of static method it belongs to a specific class. You can redeclare it in the subclass but that subclass won't know anything about the parent class' static methods because, as I said, it is specific to only that class in which it has been declared. Accessing them using object references is just an extra liberty given by the designers of Java and we should certainly not think of stopping that practice only when they restrict it
more details and example
http://faisalbhagat.blogspot.com/2014/09/method-overriding-and-method-hiding.html

Answer (score 2):

What good will it do to override static methods. You cannot call static methods through an instance.

```
MyClass.static1()
MySubClass.static1()   // If you overrode, you have to call it through MySubClass anyway.
```

EDIT : It appears that through an unfortunate oversight in language design, you **can** call static methods through an instance. Generally nobody does that. My bad.

Comment: "You cannot call static methods through an instance"  Actually, one of Java's quirks is that you CAN call static methods through an instance, even though it's an exceedingly bad idea.

Comment: Indeed Java does allow static members to be accessed via instances: see [Static variable in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506082/static-variable-in-java/12506089)

Comment: A proper modern IDE will generate a warning when you do that though, so at least you can catch it while Oracle can keep the backwards compatibility thing going.

Comment: There is nothing conceptually wrong with being able to call a static method through an instance. This is quibbling for quibbling's sake. Why should something like a Date instance NOT call its own static methods passing instance data to the function through the calling interface?

Comment: @RichieHH That is not what they are quibbling about. The question is why is it allowed to call `variable.staticMethod()`, instead of `Class.staticMethod()`, where `variable` is a variable with declared type `Class`. I agree it is bad language design.

Comment: They are allowed because the instance has access to all the static methods and so it should. It IS quibbling for quibbling's fault.

Comment: @Powerlord What *appears* to call a static method through an instance does *not* actually call the static method through the instance.

Answer (score 2):

Answer of this question is simple, the method or variable marked as static belongs to the class only, So that static method cannot be inherited in the sub class because they belong to the super class only.

Comment: Hi G4uKu3_Gaurav. Thanks for deciding to contribute. However we generally expect longer and more detailed answers than this.

Comment: @DJClayworth you should follow this link  for detailed answer  http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-overload-or-override-static-methods-in-java/

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually I'm here to be helpful to newcomers to the site, to explain how the site works for those who aren't used to it, not because I needed an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution: Use singleton instance. It will allow overrides and inheritance.

In my system, I have SingletonsRegistry class, which returns instance for passed Class. If instance is not found, it is created.

Haxe language class:

```
package rflib.common.utils;
import haxe.ds.ObjectMap;



class SingletonsRegistry
{
  public static var instances:Map<Class<Dynamic>, Dynamic>;

  static function __init__()
  {
    StaticsInitializer.addCallback(SingletonsRegistry, function()
    {
      instances = null;
    });

  } 

  public static function getInstance(cls:Class<Dynamic>, ?args:Array<Dynamic>)
  {
    if (instances == null) {
      instances = untyped new ObjectMap<Dynamic, Dynamic>();      
    }

    if (!instances.exists(cls)) 
    {
      if (args == null) args = [];
      instances.set(cls, Type.createInstance(cls, args));
    }

    return instances.get(cls);
  }


  public static function validate(inst:Dynamic, cls:Class<Dynamic>)
  {
    if (instances == null) return;

    var inst2 = instances[cls];
    if (inst2 != null && inst != inst2) throw "Can\'t create multiple instances of " + Type.getClassName(cls) + " - it's singleton!";
  }

}
```

Comment: Very cool, it's the first time I have heard about the Haxe programming language :)

Comment: This is much better implemented in Java as a static method on the class itself; `Singleton.get()`. The registry is just boilerplate overhead, and it precludes GC on the classes.

Comment: Your are right, it is a classic solution. I don't exactly remember why I chose registry, probably had some framework of thought which led to this result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple explanation. A static method is associated with a class while an instance method is associated with a particular object. Overrides allow calling the different implementation of the overridden methods associated with the particular object. So it is counter-intuitive to override static method which is not even associated with objects but the class itself in the first place. So static methods cannot be overridden based on what object is calling it, it will always be associated with the class where it was created.

Comment: How is it counter intuitive to have an `public abstract IBox createBox();` inside IBox interface? Box can implement IBox to override createBox, and have the creation of object result in a valid IBox, otherwise return a null. Constructors cannot return "null" and therefore you are forced to (1) use exceptions EVERYWHERE(what we do now), or (2) create factory classes that do what I said earlier but in a way that makes no sense to novices nor experts of Java(Which we also do now). Static unimplemented methods solve this.

Answer (score 1):

A Static method, variable, block or nested class **belongs to the entire class** rather than an object.

A Method in Java is used to expose the behaviour of an Object / Class. Here, as the method is **static** (i.e, static method is used to represent the behaviour of a class only.) **changing/ overriding** the behaviour of entire class will violate the phenomenon of one of the fundamental pillar of Object oriented programming i.e, **high cohesion**. (remember a constructor is a special kind of method in Java.)

**High Cohesion** - One class should have only one role. For example: A car class should produce only car objects and not bike, trucks, planes etc. But the Car class may have some features(behaviour) that belongs to itself only.

Therefore, while designing the java programming language. The language designers thought to allow developers to keep some behaviours of a class to itself only by making a method static in nature.

---

The below piece code tries to override the static method, but will **not** encounter any compilation error.

```
public class Vehicle {
static int VIN;

public static int getVehileNumber() {
    return VIN;
}}

class Car extends Vehicle {
static int carNumber;

public static int getVehileNumber() {
    return carNumber;
}}
```

This is because, here we are not overriding a method but we are just **re-declaring** it. Java allows re-declaration of a method (static/non-static).

Removing the static keyword from getVehileNumber() method of Car class will result into compilation error, Since, we are trying to **change** the functionality of static method which belongs to Vehicle class only.

Also, If the getVehileNumber() is declared as **final** then the code will not compile, Since the final keyword restricts the programmer from re-declaring the method.

```
public static final int getVehileNumber() {
return VIN;     }
```

Overall, this is upto software designers for where to use the static methods.
I personally prefer to use static methods to perform some actions without creating any instance of a class. Secondly, to hide the behaviour of a class from outside world.

Answer (score 0):

Now seeing above answers everyone knows that we can't override static methods, but one should not misunderstood about the **concept of accessing static methods from subclass**.

> **We can access static methods of super class with subclass reference if this static method has not been hidden by new static method defined in sub class.**

For Example, see below code:-

```
public class StaticMethodsHiding {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SubClass.hello();
    }
}


class SuperClass {
    static void hello(){
        System.out.println("SuperClass saying Hello");
    }
}


class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    // static void hello() {
    // System.out.println("SubClass Hello");
    // }
}
```

Output:-

```
SuperClass saying Hello
```

> > See  [Java oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)  and search for ***What You Can Do in a Subclass*** for details about hiding of static methods in sub class.

Thanks

Answer (score -3):

The following code shows that it is possible:

```
class OverridenStaticMeth {   

static void printValue() {   
System.out.println("Overriden Meth");   
}   

}   

public class OverrideStaticMeth extends OverridenStaticMeth {   

static void printValue() {   
System.out.println("Overriding Meth");   
}   

public static void main(String[] args) {   
OverridenStaticMeth osm = new OverrideStaticMeth();   
osm.printValue();   

System.out.println("now, from main");
printValue();

}   

}
```

Comment: No it doesn't; the static declared type of `osm` is `OverridenStaticMeth` not `OverrideStaticMeth`.

Comment: Also, I'd try to avoid using so much Meth while programming <big grin>;