# Why does this happen when I call method from a subtype object using a different supertype variable and viceversa

Tags: inheritance, static, overriding

Sorry about giving printscreen and not code snippets. Here is a printscreen of what my program displays when i run it

[image]

Ignoring line 19 and 20 in this program, my question is: Why do we have a differnce of what it is printed out when I call the static methods and when i call the overriding methods? Shouldn't the overriding methods display the same thing that was displayed when i called the static methods?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: [Can I override and overload static methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475259/can-i-override-and-overload-static-methods-in-java)

A quick summary: Static methods belong to the class instance. They cannot be overriden.

Overriding is a principle where the particular method is called at **runtime**.
In this case, the method is chosen by the compiler at **compile time**.