# Override not working even though the methods are matching

Tags: java, oop, overriding

I'm studying again some OOP concepts so I made this simple code just to see how overriding methods work and surprise, it's not working. Also, just ignore the fact that the class name is HelloWorld, it's just a file for studying purposes. It's already changed to Filha.java btw

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Oie");
    }//

    public static void imprime(int a) {
        System.out.println("27");
    }//

}//

public class Filha extends HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        imprimir();
        imprime(55);
    }//

    @Override
    public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Ola");
    }//

    @Override
    public static void imprime(int num) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }//

}//
```

Yesterday, the error was **Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem** in the *public static void main(String[] args) {*  line, but I turned off my computer, turned it on today and it's not there anymore.

Now the error is **The method imprimir() of type Filha must override or implement a supertype method** for the *public static void imprimir() {*  line. There's also the error in the main method where it's calling imprimir(), as expected.

I don't really know what other information to give since it's a simple code with a simple problem (I believe), it's also my first question so if I'm leaving anything out please ask and I'll be more throughout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475259/can-i-override-and-overload-static-methods-in-java/5436790.

Comment: Static methods cannot be overridden. They can only be hidden. Which static method is invoked is determined at compile-time—they're not runtime-polymorphic.

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/03/can-we-overload-and-override-static-method-java.html#:~:text=Answer%20is%2C%20No%2C%20you%20can,that%20is%20called%20method%20hiding.

Comment: You cannot override a static method.

Answer (score 0):

with your code

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Oie");
    }//

    public static void imprime(int a) {
        System.out.println("27");
    }//

}//

public class Filha extends HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        imprimir();
        imprime(55);
    }//

    @Override
    public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Ola");
    }//

    @Override
    public static void imprime(int num) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }//

}//
```

you are not overriding anything. If you remove the @Override the code will run normally  but only shows what you have declared within your main method, as static methods can't be overridden as below:

```
class HelloWorld {

    public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Oie");
    }//

    public static void imprime(int a) {
        System.out.println("27");
    }//

}//

public class Filha extends HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        imprimir();
        imprime(55);
    }//

    public static void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Ola");
    }//

    public static void imprime(int num) {
        System.out.println(num);
    }//

}//
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `abstract class` instead of normal class and in `HelloWorld` class you need to replace the regular methods with `abstract` methods without implementation and in the `Filha` class replace `extends` with `implements` and you will successfuly be able to `@Override` the functions

Note: static methods cannot be overriden