# PHP: Invoke static method without class name

Tags: php, oop, static-methods

I have simllar question like here: [static-method-invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629475/static-method-invocation), but in PHP. Simply, I want have class like this:

> ```
> static class ClassName{
>    static public function methodName(){
>          //blah blah blah
>    }
> }
> ```

and I want to call member method without name od class like this:

> ```
> require_once(ClassName.php);
>
> methodName();
> ```

Is it possible in PHP? Thanks for your answers!

Comment: unless you supply a wrapper function, this won't be possible, no! Why would you need this?

Comment: I would like to shorten my calling of hevy-used function. Name of class is really long and I need to use it on lot of lines. So, My idea was: create method with short name and call it without class name.

Comment: how about `use AbsurdlyElongatedClassName as A` then call with `A::method()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can not do what you're looking for. The example call you give:

```
methodName();
```

Is calling a global function. Even static class functions are global as well, they always need the class-name to be called:

```
ClassName::methodName();
```

This calls the global static class function you've created in the include file.

I can only guess what you'd like to achieve, maybe you can benefit from the feature that includes can return values:

```
static class ClassName{
   static public function methodName(){
         //blah blah blah
   }
}
return 'ClassName';
```

Including:

```
$className = require_once(ClassName.php);
$className::methodName();
```

However this won't work with `reguire_once` when the file has been loaded earlier.

You can write a wrapper function to `require_once` files, store their return value into a global context array that keeps these values based on the file-name of the include.

Keep in mind that the java language differs from PHP. The equivalent to the java static function would be the global function in PHP:

```
function methodName(){
    //blah blah blah
}
```

Including:

```
require_once(ClassName.php);
methodName();
```

That's the PHP equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

only way

```
$ClassName = 'MyClass';
require_once($ClassName.'.php');

$ClassName::methodName();
```

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 8.1, the (...) operator allows for the following syntax:

```php
<?php

echo "Define a class...\n";

class ThisIsAContainer {
    public static function thisIsAMethod(){
        echo "This method does something.";
    }
}

echo "Grab the method...\n";

$function = ThisIsAContainer::thisIsAMethod(...);

echo "Run it:\n";

$function();
```

https://3v4l.org/gtEi9