# How to describe c# interface without the constructor and with static method?

Tags: c#

I want create interface for singleton.
But interface not can ban public constructor and describ static method. how to solve this of problems?

Comment: I have to be a fortuneteller to understand this question:(

Comment: You might want to check this out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855245/abstract-base-class-to-force-each-derived-classes-to-be-singleton

Comment: static methods are not valid in an interface

Comment: It seems he wants to define the interface to force each implementation  of the interface to be Singleton.

Comment: Did you check the generic version I have suggested? It may be what you are trying to do.

Comment: I vote to reopen now, though I was one of the closers. The question is now definitely clearer, than when I voted for closing.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have a `ISingleton` interface for two reasons:

1. Interfaces cannot have static
   members
2. Interfaces cannot contain
   constructors

You could have a `ASingleton` abstract class if you liked.

Comment: Error: A static member XXX cannot be marked as override, virtual, or abstract.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, basically. Interfaces can't contain static methods, and can't put any constraints on what kind of constructors are available.

You might be interested in my notion of [static interfaces](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/08/29/lessons-learned-from-protocol-buffers-part-4-static-interfaces.aspx), which would allow the idea of enforcing a particular static member to be *present* - but it wouldn't allow you to enforce the *absence* of a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you can't use an interface for that. What you can do is create a generic singleton class:

```
public static class Singleton<T> where T : new()
{
    public static T Instance { get; private set; }

    static Singleton() { Instance = new T(); }
}
```

This way you just use one generic class for all your singletons. Of course, you won't be able to initialize the singleton in different ways for different types (which can be changed implementing an interface on the instance or deriving classes).