# Static and overriding in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, static, overriding

```
public class B {

    static int i =1;

    public static int multiply(int a,int b)
    {
        return i;
    }

    public int multiply1(int a,int b)
    {
        return i;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        B b = new A();
        System.out.println(b.multiply(5,2));
        System.out.println(b.multiply1(5,2));
    }
}

class A extends B
{
    static int i =8;

    public static int multiply(int a,int b)
    {
        return 5*i;
    }

    public int multiply1(int a,int b)
    {
        return 5*i;
    }

}
```

Output:

1

40

Why is it so? Please explain.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling static methods via references is a really bad idea - it makes the code confusing.

These lines:

```
B b = new A();
System.out.println(b.multiply(5,2));
System.out.println(b.multiply1(5,2));
```

are compiled into this:

```
B b = new A();
System.out.println(B.multiply(5,2));
System.out.println(B.multiply1(5,2));
```

Note that the calls don't rely on `b` *at all*. In fact, `b` could be null. The binding is performed based on the *compile-time* type of `b`, ignoring its value at execution time.

Polymorphism simply doesn't happen with static methods.

Comment: Small oversight; multiply1() is not static so it's compiled into `b.multiply1(5,2)` which explains the 40 (from A) and 1 (from B).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.
please correct your answer. multiply1 is not a static method.

Answer (score 5):

You can not override `static` methods - they are statically bound to the class they are defined in. Thus, unlike instance methods, they are not polymorphic at all.

In fact, `b.multiply(5,2)` should result in a compiler warning, saying that `static` method calls should be scoped with the class rather than an instance, hence the correct form would be `B.multiply(5,2)` (or `A.multiply(5,2)`). This then clarifies which method is actually called.

If you omit the compiler warning, you easily get confused :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because b is of type B. If you use eclipse you will notice a warning which indicates as much.

> The static method multiply(int, int) from the type B should be accessed in a static way