# Scala: Companion object with arguments

Tags: scala, design-patterns, singleton

I am looking for a way to initialize a `companion` object with `arguments`. I tried this, it has the risk for `re-instantiation`.

```
private[mypackage] class A(in:Int) {
  def method = {}
}

object A {

  var singleton: Option[A] = None

  def getInstance(): A = {
    if(singleton.isDefined)
      singleton.get
    else {
        throw InitializationException("Object not configured")
      }
  }

  def getInstance(in:Int): A = {
    singleton = Some(new A(in))
    singleton.get
  }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: if you need a singleton object say `Cat` you can declare `object Cat` compiler ensures single instance of `Cat` is available in that JVM instance. note that Type of `Cat` object will be `Cat.type`

Answer (score 1):

**Pure Scala way**

Scala allows you to create a singleton object of a type using `object` keyword. Scala ensures only one instance of A is available in the system.

```
private[myPackage] object A  {
  val configValue = Config.getInt("some_value")
  def fn: Unit = ()
}
```

type of A object

```
scala> object A {}
defined object A

scala> :type A
A.type
```

more about singleton objects in scala [Explanation of singleton objects in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541393/explanation-of-singleton-objects-in-scala)

**Guice Annotations**

```
import com.google.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class A (val value: Int) {
  def fn: Unit = ()
}
```

**Classic Java way**

Use `synchronized` keyword to protect the `getInstance` from creating more than one object when called. of course constructor of the class has to be `private`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `lazy val` to delay creation of your singleton, and base it on a `var` that should be updated once during start-up sequence:

```
object A {
  // will be instantiated once, on first call
  lazy val singleton: A = create()

  private var input: Option[Int] = None

  // call this before first access to 'singleton':
  def set(i: Int): Unit = { input = Some(i) }

  private def create(): A = {
    input.map(i => new A(i))
      .getOrElse(throw new IllegalStateException("cannot access A before input is set"))
  }
}
```

Comment: `lazy val` is thread-safe (and rather slow) only for 2.11.* scala. Future scala versions and dotty will use different algorithm, so one would need to add `@volatile` to save thread-safety. See http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/improved-lazy-val-initialization.html for details.

Comment: See https://d-d.me/talks/scalar2016/#/39 , "both thread-safe and thread-unsafe lazy vals.". IIRC to achieve thread-safety one would need to add @volatile.