# Java Utility Classes and Extension through Inheritance

Tags: java

I have a utility class with some static methods which I use in some places around my code. I am facing a problem now. I want to replace the functions in this utility class in order to provide better implementation. Obviously this cannot be achieved directly without some serious hacking.

My question is: what is the best way to solve this problem. How can someone still use utility classes in such a way that they can still be extended upon. I am thinking around the idea of wrapping the particular utility function for each class that makes use of them so that even if the actual utility method cannot be replaced at least it is possible to replace the class method that calls it. Still, I am curious to know about what are the best practices.

Comment: 1+ for trying to find best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why can't you just change the implementation of the static methods in the utility class.

As long as you don't change the method signatures, the users wont get affected.

Answer (score 1):

While not an exact duplicate, an answer to this can be found in the following question:

[calling a super method from a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059051/java-calling-a-super-method-from-a-static-method/5059064#5059064)

Personally, I would make them not be static methods, but make them relate to whatever they manipulate instead. If you post an example or two of your current utility methods, I can tell you how I'd handle them.

```
public interface HashAlgorithm {

    String hash(String s);

    String getType();

}

public class ReallyBadHashAlgorithm implements HashAlgorithm {
    public String hash(String s) {
        // really bad hash! I mean, really bad!
        return "HASH" + Integer.toString(s.hashCode()) + "HASH"; 
    }
    public String getType() {
        return "RRB"; // really really bad = RRB
    }
}

public class Hash<A extends HashAlgorithm> {

    String key;
    String value;
    A algorithm;

    public Hash(String key, A algorithm) {
       this.key = key;
       this.value = null;
       this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    public String getHash() {
        if(value == null) {
            value = algorithm.hash(key);
        }
        return value;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReallyBadHashAlgorithm alg = new ReallyBadHashAlgorithm();
        String key = "ABCDEFG";
        Hash hashThis = new Hash<ReallyBadHashAlgorithm>(key,alg);
        System.out.println(key.hashCode()); // to check it

        System.out.println(hashThis.getHash());

    }
```

}

And the result:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\mule\My Documents>java Hash
-488308668
HASH-488308668HASH

C:\Documents and Settings\mule\My Documents>
```

Comment: let's say that you have a static utility method for making sha1 hashes defined in utility class Util. in some places of the code you might see something like Util.sha1(something). Now let's say we want to change the sha1 function implementation with something better. not possible unless the classes are programmed somewhat differently...

Comment: The bottom line is avoid using utility classes - they aren't as utilizable as it sounds! They are nice on the surface, but they don't really lend themselves to OO principles well. Instead, make classes for things that you use, not utility classes.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't really see your problem. If the new implementation of your utility class is equivalent to the old version you can just replace it, if not, existing code will still need to be able to call the old functions so you can't change anything there. So why not just add new methods to the Utility class that can be used by new code?