# Static variable in Java

Tags: java, static

According to Java, static variable are accessible by Class name but they are also accessible by class object even though Java don't suggest it, and it gives the same answer.

I know there will be only one copy of the variable and its value will be same for all objects and other things.  Why does Java suggest to use class name instead of class object?

Comment: It makes the code more self-documenting. It's a variable of the class, not of the instance.

Comment: @BalusC so if i use object instead of class name would it be wrong way to write programs.other than making code self-documenting is there any performance reasons.

Comment: I think you've got the right instinct to want to learn the typical paradigms used by Java programmers, but I don't think there is any reason to worry about performance on this kind of micro-optimization level. Anyway, no, there shouldn't be a performance hit.

Comment: @BalusC I've read the documentation on this before, but your simple explanation finally got it through my thick skull! Thanks for that, very useful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it can be confusing! There is no dynamic dispatching on static members.

Take a look at this confusing code: (might be syntax errors; my Java is rusty)

```
public abstract class Singer {
    public static void sing() {
        System.out.println("Singing");
    }
}

public class Soprano extends Singer {
    public static void sing() {
        System.out.println("Singing in the range of C4-A5");
    }
}

public class MyDriver {

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Singer  mySoprano1 = new Soprano();
        Soprano mySoprano2 = new Soprano();
        mySoprano1.sing();
        mySoprano2.sing();
    }

}
```

Looking at `MyDriver` it's confusing because it seems like the `sing` method is polymorphic so the output should be...

```
Singing in the range of C4-A5
Singing in the range of C4-A5
```

... because both `soprano1` and `soprano2` are instances of `Soprano` - not `Singer`.

But alas, the output is actually:

```
Singing
Singing in the range of C4-A5
```

Why? Because there is no dynamic dispatch on static members, so the *declared* type of `mySoprano1` determines which `sing` method is invoked... and the declared type of `soprano1` is `Singer`, not `Soprano`.

For more, check out Puzzle 48 "All I get is static" in the book [Java Puzzlers](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/).

Comment: @Makoto, I think the point of the answer is to point out that it is ambiguous which `sing` method will be invoked since s1 is referred to as a `Singer` and s2 is referred to as a `Soprano` despite both being instances of `Soprano`.

Comment: It's not ambiguous per se - the compiler knows in the end - but for the developer it is misleading. It makes it look like `Soprano.sing()` will be invoked, when `Singer.sing()` will be invoked on account of the declared type of `mySoprano1`.

Comment: well it simply calls the sing() function..first time for a base class and then for the child class.so what if i want to call the sing() of base class using chlid class name can i do like Soprano.sing() would it call the function sing() of super class.

Comment: I suppose I'm not a fan of the example.

Comment: @RathoreSunny - I'm not sure I follow what you want. ?

Comment: to call sing() of singer class using Soprano class.it can be done by objects but can it be done by Class name

Comment: Only using the explicit class name: `Singer.sing()`. I don't think you can use the [`super` keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) from a static context.

Comment: See also [calling a super method from a static method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059051/calling-a-super-method-from-a-static-method)

Comment: that's my point objects can do that i think.But using class name its not possible.

Comment: i saw the link but as one can see still they are accessing the static function using class objects not the class name

Answer (score 4):

It is more self-documenting if you write `MyClass.staticVariable` than `myObject.staticVariable`. It tells the person looking at the code that `staticVariable` is a property of `MyClass`, as opposed to `myObject` which is a particular instance of the class.

Comment: Besides, the compiler generates exactly the same code, since at compile time it is already clear what static variable you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

One point I can think is if you use Class Reference instead of Object, JVM does not need to create a `new` Object at all to access that static variable. This is a good programming practice for performance.

Comment: You don't need an onject, though, just a reference. `Foo foo = null; foo.myStatic;` will work just fine (and not throw a NPE).