# Create instance of class or superclass from generic type

Tags: java

I'm new in Java. 
I'm developing program for Android similar to app for iOS.
One of the purposes of app - is get data from server.
Data often is **array** with **dictionaries** like "id = 1", "name = SomeName".
I've class

```
class BaseArrayList<Type extends BaseItem> extends BaseItem {

public void processObject(Map<?,?> map) {
     //......
     //Some loop body
     Type item =  (Type) Type.create();
     item.processObject(map);
     //.....
}
```

Also BaseItem have method create():

```
public static BaseItem create() {
    return new BaseItem();
}
```

It works, but for sublass of BaseItem -it doesn't work.
I found that static methods are not overriding.

So, how I can resolve this task: create custom class in array with just creating custom instances of BaseArrayList such as:

```
new BaseArrayList<SomeSublassOfBaseItem>
```

This issue resolved in ObjC like this -

```
[[memberClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: Type item = Type.newInstance();

Comment: Have a look at "Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?" http://stackoverflow.com/q/2223386/1250303

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov That's not going to work for an arbitrary type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found that static methods are not overriding.

Indeed, overriding does not work for static methods.

There are different ways to achieve what you want to do. One is to pass a `Class<Type>` object to your `processObject` method, which you can use to create instances of `Type` from by calling `newInstance()` on it:

```
public void processObject(Map<?, ?> map, Class<Type> cls) {
    // Uses the no-args constructor of Type to create a new instance
    Type item = cls.newInstance();

    // ...
}
```

Another more flexible way is to supply a factory to create instances of `Type`. A disadvantage of this is that you'd need to implement a factory for each subclass of `BaseItem` that you'd want to use for this.

```
public interface Factory<T> {
    T create();
}

// ...

public void processObject(Map<?, ?> map, Factory<Type> factory) {
    // Calls the factory to create a new Type
    Type item = factory.create();

    // ...
}

// Factory implementation for BaseItem
public class BaseItemFactory implements Factory<BaseItem> {
    @Override
    public BaseItem create() {
        return new BaseItem();
    }
}
```

Comment: An explicit factory is by far the best way to do this.

Comment: I've solved this problem by extracting superclass for BaseArrayList - So I've abstract BAArrayList<Type extends BaseItem> with abstract method newObject();