# get current class name at runtime

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I've two classes:

```
public class UThreadApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        newUThread("umain", args);
            ...
    }
    native void newUThread(String method, String[] args);
}

public class App extends UThreadApp {
    public static void umain(String[] args) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Application is executed as `java App`.

`App` inherits `main` from `UThreadApp` such that `main` calls `App.umain`. I've to get programmatically the main class name `App` from Java or JNI so as to call `App.umain` from JNI code. Do you see a way to do that?

Idioms such that `new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingClass()` don't work since they return `UThreadApp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static methods have no class, and no `this` reference. Your `App` class will “inherit” main insofar as that main is usually callable as `App.main` as well. But [you cannot override static methods](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2223386/1468366) in the common sense. Once the method got invoked, there is no way to determine what name was used to invoke it. So nothing you do, on the java side or in native code, will give you the information you desire. Apart from hacking the java executable and figuring out its command line arguments or similar brutal and unsupported approaches, that is.

*Note:* You also have an error where the static `main` tries to call the non-static `newUThread`.

What you could do is something like this, to leave the `static` scope and get a reasonable `this` pointer:

```
public class UThreadApp {
    protected void UThreadApp(String[] args) {
        newUThread("umain", args);
            ...
    }
    native void newUThread(String method, String[] args);
}

public class App extends UThreadApp {
    public void main(String[] args) {
        new App(args);
    }
    public App(String[] args) {
        super(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see... but I was trying to separate system's code (UThreadApp) from application's code (App) as much as possible. (Note: of course newUThread shoud be static). Perhaps there is a JNI function which can extract the first argument (java App)

Comment: On Unixoid systems you can have a look at `/pfoc/self/cmdline`. There might be similar solutions for other platforms. Or you might change you call requirements to always invoke `UThreadApp.main`, perhaps via the `Main-Class` of a jar filoe, and pass the name of the application to that.