# Getting an error as I try to override the method from the parent class. Why is that?

Tags: java, oop

As I try to compile the `Child` class I get the following error :

```
Child.java:2: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
1 error
```

---

Why is that ? I try to override the `init` of the parent class in the child class.

```
class Parent {
    public static void init() {
        System.out.println("From the parent class");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public static void init() {
        System.out.println("From the child class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override a static method - [you can only hide it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html). You can therefore only apply the `@Override` annotation to instance methods:

```
class Parent {
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("From the parent class");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    @Override
    public void init() {
        System.out.println("From the child class");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't override a static method in java. For more info, take a look at: [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)