# Java static function

Tags: java, function, static

I have some classes.

```
class A{    
    static void v(){
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class A1 extends A{
    static void v(){
        System.out.println("A1");
    }
}

class B <T extends A>{
     void v(){
         T.v();
     }
}
```

Why following code outputs "A"?

```
B b = new B<A1>();
b.v();
```

I thought that the code should output "A1" because `B<A1>()`.

Comment: `T extends A` <- Right there

Comment: Why should it output something else?

Comment: I thought that the code should output "A1" because B<A1>()

Comment: @dr_yand I added it to your question.

Answer (score 3):

Your `T.v()` is a `static` method call and compiles into `A.v()` because `T` erases to `A` according to its upper type bound.

Answer (score 2):

You can't override static methods in Java, you can only hide them.

Read this: [Overriding and Hiding Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html)

Answer (score 0):

Shortly java does not support overwritting static methods:

here is a possible duplicate explaining better the case:
[Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are not dispatched dynamically. The exact method to be called is resolved on compile time and it's A due to erasure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that calls to static methods are statically bound at *compile* time to the declared type of the variable. In this case, the compiler knows that `T` is an `A`.

It doesn't matter that the generic type of the local object is `A1` - the binding is made inside `B`, where `A` is the only information the compiler has about the type.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't override the function v() for class T. Since T is a subclass of A, the effect of calling T.v() equals A.v() which outputs "A".