# Can you override static method in Java? if I create same method in subclass is it compile time error?

Tags: java

I thought you can not override static method in Java but its not a compile time error to declare exactly same method in sub class, That is called method hiding in Java. But what if i have to override static method.

```
// filename Test.java
public class Test { 
  public static void foo() { 
    System.out.println("Test.foo() called "); 
  } 
  public static void foo(int a) { 
    System.out.println("Test.foo(int) called "); 
  } 
  public static void main(String args[]) { 
    Test.foo(); 
    Test.foo(10); 
  } 
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Give us a case where you HAVE to override a static method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

Comment: This seems like it may be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: class Base {
     
    // Static method in base class which will be hidden in subclass 
    public static void display() {
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Base");
    }
     public void print()  {
         System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Base");}}
// Subclass
class Derived extends Base {
    public static void display() {
         System.out.println("Static or class method from Derived");}
   public void print() {
         System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Derived");

Comment: Next time dont copy and paste just a question from the internet just for receiving up votes! Try and do a research and try to learn from this research. Your question is exactly the same with the 10th question of this page: http://www.java67.com/2012/09/top-10-tough-core-java-interview-questions-answers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't override static methods in Java, because, polymorphism and static won't work together. And static methods are invoked on Class, not in instances.

You can hide a super class static method in sub class.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try to hide a super class static method as you said.