# Get static field from instance

Tags: java, inheritance, static

I have a class with multiple subclasses:

```
class A {

    static int i = 5;
}

class B extends A{

    static int i = 6;
}

class C extends A {

    static int i = 7;
}
```

I'm trying to write a comparator that takes two `A`'s and compares them based on their values of `i`. I'm stuck at:

```
public int compare(A a1, A a2) {

}
```

Neither `a1.i` nor `a1.class.getField("i").getInt(null);` work.

How can I get the value of the static field from the object?

Comment: Member variables are not polymorphic in Java (whether static or non-static).  The best you could do is indeed use reflection, but there's probably a better way to achieve whatever the overall goal is here.

Comment: They're not polymorphic?

Comment: No, only non-static methods are.

Comment: No, they're not. You have to change your design.

Comment: What if I add `getI()` to `A`?

Comment: @AnubianNoob: You'd need to make it non-static, and override it in each derived class.

Comment: It will call the `static` method on A, not on the subclasses.

Comment: You cannot override `static` methods in java neither.

Comment: Could I add an abstract method `getI()` and use that? Or make `i` final and not static?

Comment: Related: [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2223386/1065197)

Comment: What if I make `i` non-static? (lemme test that)

Comment: How about defining an Interface HasI with a getI() method and making A, B, and C implement HasI? Your compare will be public int comapre(HasI a, HasI b)

Comment: @AlexandreSantos In that case, I could just add and abstract `getI()` to `A` and have `B` and `C` override that, right? (Also that's worth an answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
a1.i
```

Because a1 is declared a `A`, it is equivalent to `A.i`. The compiler should tell you about that with a warning. Most IDE will do that to and give a little message about what to do about it.

```
a1.class.getField("i").getInt(null);
```

Can't work because `class` is static.

You can use

```
a1.getClass().getDeclaredField("i").getInt(null);
```

`getClass` is an instance method to get the class of an object. `getDeclaredField` will return all fields, while `getField` will only return the public ones.

Comment: *The compiler should complain about that* compiler won't complain about it, it will show a warning and sadly we programmers tend to ignore warnings because we only care for errors :)

Comment: by `complain` I mean `show a warning`. I will edit to make it more explicit.

Comment: Compiler complain is usually known as a compiler error.