# Calling methods of super-classes

Tags: java, subclass, superclass

This program is supposed to individually call the `funFact` of each subclass but instead, it calls the `funFact`  method only from the `Mammal` class. What am I doing wrong?

```
 public class MammalFacts{
        public static class Mammal{
            public static String funFact(){
                return "If you are reading this, there's a 70% chance you're a mammal";
            }//end funFact

        }//end mammal
        public static class Primate extends Mammal{
            public static String funFact(){
                return "All primates can fly";
            }
        }//end Primate
        public static class Monkey extends Primate{
            public static String funFact(){
                return "Monkies will rule the earth someday";
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[]args){
            Mammal[]i = new Mammal[3];
            i[0] = new Mammal();
            i[1] = new Primate();
            i[2] = new Monkey();

            for(int c = 0; c < i.length; c++){
                System.out.println(i[c].funFact());
            }
        }//end of main
    }//end MammalFacts
```

Comment: Why is `funFact()` static ?

Comment: If you are creating each animal as an object, then you don't need the funFact function to be static

Comment: Check this out too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods

Answer (score 6):

`funFact` is static. Overriding doesn't work on static methods.

Remove the `static` keyword from all your methods (as you are calling them via an instance reference anyway) and it will work as you expected.

Answer (score 2):

If you "override" the static method, you are **hiding** the method, not really overriding.

read this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html

the "Static Methods" section exactly answers your question.