# How to override parametrized static method in Java?

Tags: java, overriding, parametric-polymorphism

How can I override in a class this method from the extended class?

```
protected static <T extends Object> T getObject(ResultSet data){
    return null; 
}
```

I'm using java 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot override static methods in `Java`, because the `Java` design is so in short, no matter generic they or not. Please take a look on detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods).

Comment: thanks. I feeling like a beginner... definitively today is not my best day :-)