# overriding instance method with static keyword

Tags: java

How can I override instance methods of super class as static in subclass? I think this is impossible but is there any indirect way?

```
public class A {
   public void test(){
       System.out.println("");
   }
}

public class B extends A{
    public static void test(){//test() in B cannot override test() in A 
    //overriding method is static

   }
}
```

Comment: Captain obvious: make it not static?

Comment: You can't override an instance method with a class method.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods

Answer (score 8):

You can't, since a static method is not an instance method. You could override the instance method with an instance method that calls the static method.

```
public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void test(){
        staticTest();
    }
    public static void staticTest() {
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how much sense that would make though.

Comment: It won't make any difference! :D

Comment: @Pratik What do you mean? If you call `test()` on an instance of B, it will execute `B`'s version of `test()`, which would call the static method.