# Calling the Static Method of

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, static, call

This is a bit weird and might ring of iffy syntax but hold with me. I've been trying for three months and I'm convinced that I need a way to do this:

```
public abstract class Sup{
    ...
    //This is implemented here because I cannot create an abstract static
    //only implemented by the children but called statically by methods in
    //the parent (more info later on in the post):
    protected static Class<? extends Sup> getTypeClass(){ return Sup.class };
    public static void init(){
        ...
        alreadyDeclaredHashMap.put(getTypeClass(), hashMapOfOtherStuff);
    }
}

public class A extends Sup{
    static{
        init();
    }
    protected static void getTypeClass(){ return A.class };
}
public class B extends Sup{
    static{
        init();
    }
    protected static void getTypeClass(){ return B.class };
}
... and so on.
```

So that if I were to print out `alreadyDeclaredHashMap`, it would look like:

```
    class A -> hashMapOfOtherStuff
    class B -> hashMapOfOtherStuff
    class C -> hashMapOfOtherStuff
    ...
```

But instead it prints:

```
    class Sup -> hashMapOfOtherStuff
    class Sup -> hashMapOfOtherStuff
    class Sup -> hashMapOfOtherStuff
    ...
```

Because the extending classes hide `getTypeClass()` but can't override it. This is just an example. In reality, I am making a Units system and I have a lot of methods depending on `getTypeClass()` and would ***really*** love to not have to rewrite them in every extending class (of which there are an indefinite number) with the only difference in implementation being the class name.

Many thanks!

P.S. These methods *do* have to be static because they are being called statically (and I would rather not have to create a dummy instance or reflection just to call them).

Comment: No, this is terrible design. Please provide the "Units" use case, so we can help you with that. This is an XY-problem.

Comment: *I've been trying for three months and I'm convinced that I need a way to do this*; **after** trying for three months, why are you so adamantly convinced?

Comment: How can methods with return type void return anything? When overriding add @Override annotation to make sure that you are overriding something from the superclass. Also static methods cannot be overridden in Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods

Comment: What do you mean depending on getTypeClass()? They have switch case? If yes then it would not matter having to rewrite them. If no then share your use case. It may be better done via strategy pattern or generics. Not sure what can be the exact one unless you provide the problem instead of your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get that to work. The static code in class `sup` has no knowledge of class `A` and class `B`, even when the `init` method is invoked from one of them.

Static methods are not "[virtual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function)", so calling `getTypeClass()` from the static code in `Sup` will call that implementation, not any of the subclass implementation.

Now, if you *want* to reuse the `init` method from `A` and `B`, you'll have to pass as parameters.

```
public abstract class Sup{
    ...
    public static void init(Class<? extends Sup> typeClass) {
        ...
        alreadyDeclaredHashMap.put(typeClass, hashMapOfOtherStuff);
    }
}

public class A extends Sup {
    static {
        init(A.class);
    }
}
public class B extends Sup {
    static {
        init(B.class);
    }
}
```