# How to call a method two different classes have in common?

Tags: android

My question is a design question. I have two custom fragments `CustomFrag1` and `CustomFrag2`. Both these fragments have a method `swapCursor`.

`CustomFrag1`:

```
public class CustomFrag1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // .... code
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // .... code

        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(); 

        // .... code
    }

    public static void swapCursor(final Cursor cursor, Activity ctx){

        // .... code
    }

}
```

`CustomFrag2`:

```
public class CustomFrag1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // .... code
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // .... code

        MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(); 

        // .... code
    }

    public static void swapCursor(final Cursor cursor, Activity ctx){

        // .... code
    }

}
```

I don't want to make a seperate adapter class for each fragment. I do however, want to call `swapCursor` in the adapter class. If the adapter has been instantied from `CustomeFrag1` I want `swapCurosr` to swap the cursor in `CustomFrag1`. If the adapter has been instantiated from `CustomeFrag2` I want `swapCurosr` to swap the cursor in `CustomFrag2`.

Is it possible to pass in an instance of the Fragment...

```
MyAdapter mAdapter = new MyAdapter(this);
```

...and somehow represent that instance with a generic variable that has `swapCursor` defined as a method? If not, what strategy can I use? Interfaces? Generics? Something?

**edit**

I tried inheriting `swapCursor` but that would just swap out the cursor out on the parent and not the child.

Comment: *I tried inheriting swapCursor but that would just swap out the cursor out on the parent and not the child*, why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

swapCursor shouldn't be static at the first place, because there's no inheritance for static methods.

You could create an interface (SwappableCursor as a name hint) which has a method swapCursor, then all of your fragments can implement this interface. So that you'll have to implement swapCursor.

In MyAdapter's constructor you can add a parameter which has the type of your interface (SwappableCursor). You'll be able to invoke swapCursor method.

Comment: Thanks. That was the strategy I was trending towards. Why can't static methods be inherited?

Comment: Here are some answers which probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods The first answer is quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Use interfaces.

```
public interface SwapFrag { 
   public swapCursor(final Cursor cursor, Activity ctx);
}
```

your fragments need to implement SwapFrag:

`public class CustomFrag1 extends Fragment implements SwapFrag`

and also need to implements the swapCursor method.

```
@Override
public static void swapCursor(final Cursor cursor, Activity ctx) {
  ...
}
```