# override static method functionality

Tags: java, static

We have class library as

```
class A {
    public void callWorkflow()  {
      B b = new B();
    }
}

class B {
    public void callStatic() {
      C.someMethod();
    }
}

class C {
    public static someMethod() {}
}
```

We are actually trying to change functionality of static method `someMethod`. Is there a way to solve this problem without changing call hierarchy?

Comment: You might find your answer in [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2223386/1072229)

Answer (score 3):

You can't just `Override` a `static` method. In my opinion, remove `static` from the method `someMethod()`, then create an object of class `C` inside class `B`. Then call the method.

```
Class A{
    public void callWorkflow()  {
      B b = new B();}
}
Class B{
    public void callStatic(){
      C c = new C();
      c.someMethod();}
}
Class C{
    public someMethod(){}
}
```

Comment: The Class C is in an external library, so its not possible to change implementation there.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to override a `static` method.

That's why one of these approaches is preferred to calling static methods:

- Inject another object (service) that will provide the functionality in a non-static method and call it through the injected object
- Make the static method a thin wrapper that just delegates the work to some non-static object that can be configured (like in slf4j's logger)