# @Override doesn´t work for a method but for others

Tags: java, android, overriding

I don´t know why I can not override one method but other I can for others.

Here is the method I want to override in another class (without extending the class with the method):

```
public static void onOk() throws Exception {
    throw new Exception("test");
}
```

I am trying to override but it says "Annotation not allowed here" but below the method are a lot of other methods whose get just overridden.

```
@Override  <- red underlined error "Annotation not allowed here"
InputAdressDialogFragment.onOk(){
}

@Override  <- works! The compiler accepts
    public View onCreateView(
```

Comment: In the first example you're *calling* a method. In the second example you're *declaring* a method. Note that you can't override static methods anyway, and you *have* to extend a class to override a method from it. It's really unclear what you're trying to do, to be honest...

Comment: can you not see the different in the structure of `@Override public View onCreateView(...` and `@Override InputAdressDialogFragment.onOk(){
` ?

Comment: You can not override `static` methods. To override some methods it must be available in its parent class and aslo not static. Here You are directly calling method name by its class reference. So It is not possible to `override` `onOk()`  method

Comment: Just for the record: a **compiler error** is not at all the same as **an exception gets thrown**. I reworded your question about that.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, @Override is for **overriding** methods.

Static methods can't be overridden - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods) for details.

That is one of the reasons why using *static* is regarded an abnormality in good OOP.

Answer (score 0):

A class `Child` where  `Child extends Parent` can only `override` methods defined in its `super` class `Parent` which are non static.

In the static context there is no implicit reference of current object (`this`) as static methods do not need any object upon which to invoke like normal non static methods. Static methods are not object based but based on class.