# How to override static methods in a subclass?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, static, overriding

1. For what version of Java is it planned to implement the possibility to override static methods?
2. For what year it would be?
3. How to achieve similar thing in Java 8?
4. Is there some hack for Oracle JVM?
5. Are there some other virtual machines or compilers, able to override static methods?

I see that there is confusion about word "static" in java. What I am really looking for, is the **methods of the class**, (it is irrelevant, if you name them "static method", "class method" or anything else..)

Comment: Static method cannot be overridden because it's not associated with any instance of a class. Period.

Comment: You can't override static methods. You are not going to be able to override static methods.

Comment: @Yahya In theory, it is not true, because "class methods" can be overriden. And in practice, it is not true either, because there are many languages, what enable it. Question is inly, when oracle will enable it in java....

Comment: @khelwood Sorry, I really do not understand, what do you like to help? Are you a oracle employer with future plan knowing?

Comment: Future features are discussed using the JCP. It is **not** about some people at Oracle secretly making such decisions. It is a *open community process*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

Answer (score 1):

That is the whole point why many people consider **static** to be an abnormality for good OOP: it **kills** polymorphism (besides introducing **tight** coupling between your classes).

Thus the simply answer is: *overriding* and *static* do not go together. Not with Java versions before 8 or 9; and most likely: also never in the future - I am not aware of **any** plans / projects / JCPs to change that.

In that sense, the only answer is: simply avoid using it.

If at all, you put it on small helper methods that are "self-contained" (meaning they do some simple functional thing that works fine in your unit-test environment). As soon as *static* gets into your way of easily unit-testing code, you are going down the wrong road.

When you find *static* in legacy code you have to deal with - then consider defining an interface for the underlying functionality so that you can decouple your code from the actual static methods.

Comment: Thank you for useful text. But mainly I am looking for answer to my original question(s). So, OK, it is important to have good design of the software. But in case, there exist "class methods", there is no reason to force programmer to only one approach to "class methods inheritance" (as not to allow inherit them).

Comment: Well. That is simply how things are in Java. Arguing about a design decision made almost 20 years ago isn't too productive in my eyes.

Comment: Generics arrived. When will this type of inheritence follow?

Comment: Generics fixed a big problem. And even that was done in a "super soft" way to **not** break backwards compatibility (from a JVM perspective). And many years later, we still don't have "real" generics (that work for primitive types, or would be "reifable"). Beyond that: genercis didn't fall from the sky. There were several projects upfront to figure how to do it; and zillions of discussions took place. And as said: I am not aware of any JCP that would ask for this. Seriously: I am working with Java for 20 years, I know people who once worked on javac ...

Comment: In other words: I have *some* insight into the Java language world. Guess what: I think you are the **first** person I ever met who asked to enhance Java to allow for polymorphic static calls. Please let that sink in. It doesn't make sense to argue here. If you want this feature, you go forward and put up a JCP entry; and convince people that this is required. Good luck with that!