# Work around for overriding abstract static method in Java?

Tags: java, static, overriding, abstract, utility

Working on a customised JSON Converter to comply with company standard (basically adding many tags and handling for enum).  The converter only works for objects with a public nullary constructor, so it had some problem with those objects enhanced by Spring and it has to workaround by something like this:
`((Advised) advised).getTargetSource().getTargetClass();`

The final product works pretty well, but having Spring library imported makes it a bit too large and we decided to have 2 different classes, one for projects which are using Spring and the other for those aren't.

Ideally, the 2 Converters should look something like this:

JsonConverter.java

```
public class JsonConverter {
    // public static toObject(){...}
    // public static toJSON(){...}
    // other methods
    protected static resolveTargetClass(Object obj){return obj.getClass();}
}
```

SpringJsonConverter.java

```
public class SpringJsonConverter extends JsonConverter {
    protected static resolveTargetClass(Object obj){
        if(obj instanceof Advised)
            ((Advised) obj).getTargetSource().getTargetClass();
        return obj.getClass();
    }
}
```

And just as everyone knows, this won't work as `resolveTargetClass` is static and not overridable.  Is there any elegant way to do this?  I would like to keep everything static as this converter had already been used by many projects and fixing it would cost so much time.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seriously: don't use *static* here.

*static* leads to tight coupling between classes, and as you figured yourself: it "kills" polymorphism. In that sense: it is the opposite of good practices. Not always, but as soon as it hampers your ability to create a **good** design, *static* is obviously the wrong approach.

Thus: simply drop the **static** keyword from your current code. Yes, that will cost you **now**. But it enables you to do the *right* thing in the future.

Comment: my company is advocating "WRITE EVERY TWICE" practice instead of working as DRY as possible, as copy-and-paste is really cheap at the beginning, even the maintenance afterwards would definitely be an ordeal :(

Comment: if only possible instead this static stuff also: for example declaring `JsonConverter` as an interface and implementing `JsonConverterFactory` that returns correct impl by checking this `Object obj` might be wiser considering the future