# Performance difference between static and instance variables

Tags: java, static, instance, instance-variables

> An instance variable is one per Object, every object has its own copy of instance variable.
>
> A static variable is one per Class, every object of that class shares the same Static variable.

```
class MyStaticClass{
  private static int myStaticInt;

  public static int getMyStaticInt() {return myStaticInt;}
}
```

---

```
class MyInstanceClass{
  private int myNonStaticInt;

  public int getMyNonStaticInt() {return myNonStaticInt;}
}
```

Is there a performance difference between either? Is it more expensive to call one over the other?

```
int i = MyStaticClass.getMyStaticInt();
```

**OR:**

```
int i = new MyInstanceClass().getMyNonStaticInt();
```

Comment: They are not equivalent, so the question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a matter of performance. static and instance variables have a different purpose.

Using

```
int i = new MyInstatnceClass().getMyNonStaticInt();
```

is almost certainly useless, since each time you call `new MyInstatnceClass()` you create a new `MyInstatnceClass` instance, having a new `myNonStaticInt` instance variable. Since you are not keep a reference to the created instance, you cannot retrieve the same instance variable twice, which makes it useless.

If you need a single copy of a variable to be shared across all instances of the class, `static` variable is the way to go.

That said, the latter call is also more expansive, since it involves creation and initialization of an instance of your `MyInstatnceClass` class (in addition to loading and initialzing the class if it's the first access that class).

On the other hand, `MyStaticClass.getMyStaticInt()` only loads and initializes the class `MyStaticClass` if it's the first access of that class. It doesn't have to create any instance of that class.

Comment: @Program-Me-Rev Changing the name of the variable and getter method doesn't affect my answer. `int i = new MyInstatnceClass().getMyNonStaticInt();` still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Eran.  I made a trypo err. I meant `int i = new MyInstatnceClass().getMyNonStaticInt();`. Your answer answers my concern except the first part that draws from the error I made sorry. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: While the info in this answer is correct, it doesn't actually answer the OP: they want to know if either a static or an instance method call is more performant/ less expensive than the other, not what the types of methods are useful for. The object instantiation in the example isn't part of what they want evaluated; it's just necessary boilerplate to make it syntactically correct.

Comment: @errantlinguist I disagree with your interpretation of the question.The OP asked to compare performance of two lines of code, and one of them contains object instantiation, so I see no reason to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

Since instance methods can be polymorphically [overridden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding), a very naive JVM implementation must at least initially use a [virtual mehod table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_method_table) to find the appropriate method to call. Classes themselves, however are *not* polymorphic and class methods cannot be overridden. Due to this, [they have a simpler lookup mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223405/1391325).

**However**, real-world JVMs are incredibly smart and can tell which methods are never overridden and optimize this lookup away. In other words, in all but the most contrived instances with non-existent JVMs will there be a difference in performance. Instead, use static methods to represent functionalities relevant to the entire class of objects itself rather than to a single instance thereof.