# How to call the correct factory method of a generic type?

Tags: java, generics, factory-method

I'm trying to write a generic class, that can create an instance of its generic type, by invoking a static factory method of that type's class:

```
class Test<T extends Parent> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<Child>();
    }

    private Test() {
        System.out.println(Child.newInstance());
        System.out.println(T.newInstance());
    }
}

abstract class Parent {
    static <T extends Parent> T newInstance() {
        return null;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    static Child newInstance() {
        return new Child();
    }
}
```

I expected that `Child.newInstance()` and `T.newInstance()` would call the same method, since the type `T` was set as `Child`. But instead `T.newInstance()` calls its parent's class method and returns `null`, while the direct call `Child.newInstance()` returns a new `Child` object.
Can someone explain me please, where my misunderstanding in the Java Generics logic is, and if there is any other clean way to create an instance of a generic type?

**Edit:** I'm not trying to override a static method, I'm just trying to hide it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to type erasure, we do not know what the type argument is.  Thus, at run time, we do not know whether it is a `Test<Parent>`, a `Test<Child>`, a `Test<Chicken>`, etc.

If you want to use the type parameter, you will need to pass in the relevant `Class` object and use reflection on it, like so:

```
public class Test<T extends Parent> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test<Child>(Child.class);
    }

    private Test(Class<T> clazz) {
        System.out.println(Child.newInstance());
        try {
            System.out.println(clazz.getDeclaredMethod("newInstance").invoke(null));
        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination. Since I just need to create an instance, and don't actually require the factory method to be called, using `clazz.newInstance()` seems to solve my problem aswell.

Comment: It does, but note that it does not use the `Child.newInstance()` method to do so (rather the default constructor).

Answer (score 0):

Due to java's type erasure, during run time every generic object is replaced with its upper-bound. So in your code:

```
class Test<T extends Parent> {

private Test() {
    System.out.println(Child.newInstance());
    System.out.println(T.newInstance());
}
```

}

Since `Parent` is the upper bound, `test()` ends up compiling into the following, regardless of what generic parameter you specify outside of the class:

```
private Test() {
    System.out.println(Child.newInstance());
    System.out.println(Parent.newInstance());
}
```