# Why is superclass method called while that method is overriden? (from OCA practice test)

Tags: java, static, overriding, method-hiding

From question three in [these OCA practice questions (pdf)](http://education.oracle.com/education/downloads/Exam808_SampleQuestion.pdf):

```
abstract class Writer {
   public static void write() {
      System.out.println("Writing...");
   }
}

class Author extends Writer {
   public static void write() {
      System.out.println("Writing book");
   }
}

public class Programmer extends Writer {
   public static void write() {
      System.out.println("Writing code");
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Writer w = new Programmer();
      w.write();
   }
}
```

The output is `Writing...`.

I don't understand why. As `Programmer` overrides `Writer`'s write method, I thought it should call the method in `Programmer` and not in `Writer`.

Why?

Comment: static methods cannot be overridden.

Comment: static methods can not be overriden, only hidden. You declare your object as type of superclass, so that's the one that will be taken

Comment: A static method is not associated with any instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to understand two points here.

There is no overriding concept in case of `static` members. They are simply `static` and never change based on instance.

And `static` members bind to class rather than instance. So no matter what is the instance, they look the type they got called and execute.

Comment: I would have upvoted this if you hadn't misused code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: Ahh .. sorry. My bad. Will keep in mind. I kept using `ctrl+k` unnecessarily .

Answer (score 1):

The type of the reference is `Writer`. You have called a static method for which overriding isn't applied - the method from the `Writer` is going to be invoked.

The mechanism is called [method hiding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.2).

---

Check out these cases:

```
new Programmer().write();             // code  [Programmer]
((Writer)new Author()).write();       // ...   [Writer]

new Author().write();                 // book  [Author]
((Writer)new Programmer()).write();   // ...   [Writer]

new Writer() {{}}.write();            // ...   [Writer]
```

Answer (score 1):

As we know, `static` methods cannot be overridden. If we try to do so, it turns out to be method hiding instead. In the above case, both class- `Writer` and `Programmer` contain `write()` method.

When `Programmer` extends the `Writer` class and provides its own implementation of the `write()` method, it just hides the `Writer` implementation of it.

Now, on runtime, the compiler just checks the Reference type (since it is a static method, compiler is not concerned about the object created to call the method. Remember, static methods are class methods). Hence, compiler checks and finds that reference `w` is of type `Writer`, it calls the `Writer` version of the `write` method instead.
If the methods would not have been `static`, what you expect would have been the output instead.

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer myself.

There is no such thing as overriding a static method in Java. This is why when you call a static method from the superclass reference, the superclass static method will be called.

So

```
public class SuperClass {
    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing Super");
    }
    public void writeMore() {
        System.out.println("super something");
    }
}
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {
    public static void write() {
        System.out.println("Writing Sub");
    }
    public void writeMore() {
        System.out.println("sub something");
    }
}
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SuperClass super = new SubClass();
        super.write();
        super.writeMore();
    }
}
```

Will output

```
Writing super
sub something
```

If you want to call the static write() method from the subclass. You have to reference it from a subclass. E.g.:

```
SubClass sub = new Subclass();
sub.write();
```

Some sources where I learned about this:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/can-we-overload-or-override-static-methods-in-java/
[Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

Comment: Found the answer yourself after you had already been told six times. I don't know what the scare-quotes around "'allow'" are supposed to mean. The fact is that there is *no such thing* as overriding static methods, contrary to the assertion in your question. Yon don't need any reference other than the JLS.

Comment: You are right, I did not word that sentence in a way that represents what is actually happening. I have edited it to say that there isn't overriding static methods in Java.