# Java static methods vs overriding

Tags: java, overriding, static-methods

Trying to work on an example from a book on method overriding.
The code has two classes Veggies and Pumpkin.The only confusion i have is if the object of pumpkin is assigned to the myveggie object, why does it call the  method of veggies class since the object is from derived class.
I am sure this has something to do with static method,but I could get a more clear idea.

```
 class Veggies {
        public static void staticMethod(){
            System.out.println("Veggies static method");
        }
    public void instancemethod(){
        System.out.println("Veggies instance method");
    }
}
public class Pumpkin extends Veggies{
        public static void staticMethod(){
            System.out.println("Pumpkin static method");
        }
        @Override
        public void instancemethod(){
            System.out.println("Pumpkin instance method");
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Pumpkin myPumpkin=new Pumpkin();
            Veggies myveggie=myPumpkin;
            myveggie.staticMethod();
            myveggie.instancemethod();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Any sane IDE will warn you that you call a static method as instance method.

Comment: Static methods are methods that are relative to a class, not to an instance. In my opinion, you should never call static methods on an instance (i.e. I would replace `myveggie.staticMethod()` with `Veggies.staticMethod()`), it is confusing

Comment: i think that there is a problem with the inner class, if you seperate them in two different classes it will work fine

Comment: Sorry,that seemed like an inner class . I edited it.

Comment: I got the answer, haters can keep downvoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this question:

- [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)

explains, static methods cannot be overridden in Java.

What you have in your example, is code that is calling a static method via an instance.  This is bad practice.

What actually happens is that the static type of the variable (not the reference!) is resolved at compile time to a class.  In this case, the class is `Veggies`.  Then the compiler inserts a call to the static method of that class; i.e. `Veggies.staticMethod()`.

Which is confusing ... because it looks like you *should* be dispatching to a static method associated with the reference.  But that is not how Java works.

That's why this is bad practice, and why a lot of IDEs will warn you about it.

Comment: So despite the object referrence, it still basically resolves to Veggies.staticMethod()?

Comment: @Bissisingh That's it, if you call a static method what decide which method is called is defined by the type of the variable not the type of the object referred by.