# Can we override static methods ? Why the output is so?

Tags: java, overriding

```
class Base {

    public static void display() {
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Base");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Base");
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {

    public static void display() {
        System.out.println("Static or class method from Derived");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Non-static or Instance method from Derived");
    }
}

// Driver class   
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Base obj1 = new Derived();
        obj1.display();
        obj1.print();
    }
}
```

The output of this code is showing -

```
Static or class method from Base
Non-static or Instance method from Derived
```

Can anyone explain me why is it so ??

Comment: See below post: [Why doesn't Java allow overriding of static methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223386/why-doesnt-java-allow-overriding-of-static-methods)