# call a function in different class in python

Tags: python

This is my code. I am a beginner in Python. I try to call `func` in `func2` and `func3`of class `Apple`. After I Google my problem, I found that it could work by using `@staticmethod`, but I would like to figure out another method without using `@staticmethod`. In `func3`, I didn't use `@staticmethod`, so it has a error: `print(mycall.func3(3) )
TypeError: func3() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`
Does anyone know how to fix my problem? Thank you.

```
class mango:
    def func(self):
        a=8
        b=9
        return a+b       


class Apple:

    @staticmethod
    def func2(x,y):
        temp=mango()
        c=temp.func()
        z=x+y+c    
        return z


    def func3(val):
        temp = mango()
        d = temp.func()
        output = d + val
        return output


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print "Hello, Python!"

    a = []
    b =[]
    ans = Test(a,b)
    print(ans.cc)
    mycall = Apple()
    print(mycall.func2(2,3)) 
    print(mycall.func3(3) )
```

Comment: `def funcx(self, par1, par2)` add self to class method

Comment: BTW: when you call `mycall.func3(3)` then it treated almost like  `func3(mycall, 3)` so you need `self` to get `mycall`

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you create a method (instance's function), you need to give it a parameter `self`. It's how it works.

So, you need to change:

```
def func3(val):
```

to:

```
def func3(self, val):
```

Comment: *instance's function* will be a better term instead of *class' function*

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should be defining `func3` function with `@staticmethod` decorator. But since you mentioned, you do not want to define it as static method, in order to fix the error you may define `self` as first argument in `func3`. Hence the definition of `func3` should be like:

```
def func3(self, val):
# instead of > def func3(val):
```

Reason is, when you are making a call to the function like:

```
mycall.func3(3)
```

Python passes reference of `mycall` as first argument and remaining parameters as the rest of arguments. This call will be received by function as:

```
func3(mycall, 3)
```

Hence, in the above function call you are passing 2 parameters, but your current implementation `func3` accepts only one. This is mentioned in error as well:

```
TypeError: func3() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

**Why I suggested to define it as static method, i.e with `@staticmethod` decorator?** You are currently not using any reference to the class' instance (i.e. `self`) within your function.

---

Must Read References:

- [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self)
- [What is the advantage of using static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438473/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

When you create methods inside classes (in this case, *func2* and *func3* inside *Apple*), Python treats the first argument as `self`, **regardless of what you call that argument**.

Essentially, what is happening is:

```
class MyClass(object):
    #stuff
    def myfunc(self, arg1):
        #do stuff
        return arg1
```

Then, in `if __name__ == '__main__':`

```
mycall = MyClass()
print(mycall.myfunc(5)) #In this instance, 5 is passed as arg1
```

So in order to fix your code, try:

```
def func3(self, val):
        temp = mango()
        d = temp.func()
        output = d + val
        return output
```

It's worth mentioning that if you aren't using the instance itself, then you might as well use `@staticmethod`.

Read more: [Why do you need explicitly have the "self" argument into a Python method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282/why-do-you-need-explicitly-have-the-self-argument-into-a-python-method) .