# When to us static methods vs. functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

When should I use static methods and functions? Let me provide a current example. I have a class that holds stock data, and one of my static methods in the class is as follows:

```
class Stock:
    @staticmethod
    def percent_change(old, new):
        return ((new - old) / old) * 100
```

Would it make more sense to just create the static method as a function outside of the class? As it stands, I need to call percent_change on a Stock object, but if I created a function outside of the class, I could just call the function by itself. Any thoughts?

Comment: Somewhat of an opinion-based question, but in general, prefer a function unless you can make a strong argument for why your code would be improved by making a static method instead.

Comment: If this function would only ever be called on `Stock` objects, then it makes sense to leave it as shown.

Comment: Static methods can be used to group some utility function together with a class, like the one you have.Have a look here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438473/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-static-methods-in-python)

Comment: I see. I think it might make sense to keep it as a static method for now because the only class I have so far is the Stock class, so I'd only call the method on Stock objects anyways. Thank you.