# What is "static method" in python

Tags: python, static-methods

I'm quite new to python, and could not understand what is static method in python(for example `__new__()`) and what does it do. Can anyone possibly explain it? Thanks a million

Comment: To understand what `__new__()` is please see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names it's very well explained there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the advantage of using static methods in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438473/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-static-methods-in-python)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you already read this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)

Especially this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods

### Explanation

In OOP you define **classes** that you later on **instantiate**. A class is nothing more than a blueprint: Once you instantiate objects from a class your object will follow exactly the blueprint of your class. That means: If you define a field named "abc" in your class you will later on have a field "abc" in your object. If you define a method "foo()" in your class, you will later on have a method "foo()" to be invoked **on your object**.

Please note that this "on your object" is essential: You **always** instantiate a class and **then** you can invoke the method. This is the "normal" way.

A **static method** is different. While a normal method always requires to have an instance (where you then can invoke this method at) a static method does **not**. A static method exists independently from your instances (that's why it is named "static"). So a static method is associated with your class definition itself and therefore is always there and therefore can be invoked only at your class itself. It is completely independent from all instances.

That's a static method.

Python's implementation is a bit ... well ... simple. In details there are deviations from this description above. But that does not make any difference: To be in line with OOP concepts you always should use methods exactly as described above.

### Example

Let's give you an example:

```py
class FooBar:

  def someMethod(self):
    print("abc")
```

This is a regular (instance) method. You use it like this:

```py
myObj = FooBar()
myObj.someMethod()
```

If you have ...

```py
myObjB = FooBar()
myObjB.someMethod()
```

... you have an additional instance and therefore invoking `someMethod()` on this second instance will be the invocation of a second `someMethod()` method - defined at the second object. This is because you instantiate objects before use so all instances follow the blueprint `FooBar` defined. All instances therefore receive some kind of copy of `someMethod()`.

(In practice Python will use optimizations internally, so there actually is only one piece of code that implements your `someMethod()` in memory, but forget about this for now. To a programmer it *appears* as that every instance of a class will have a copy of the method `someMethod()`. And *that's* the level of abstraction that is relevant to us as this is the "surface" we work on. Deep within the implementation of a programming or script language things might be a bit different but this is not very relevant.)

Let's have a look at a static method:

```py
class FooBar:

  @staticmethod
  def someStaticMethod():
    print("abc")
```

Such static methods can be invoked like this:

```py
FooBar.someStaticMethod()
```

As you can see: No instance. You directly invoke this method in the context of the class itself. While regular methods work on the particular instance itself - they typically modify data within this instance itself - a class method does not. It could modify static (!) data, but typically it does not anyway.

Consider a static method a special case. It is rarely needed. What you typically want if you write code is *not* to implement a static method. Only in very specific situations it makes sense to implement a static method.

### The `self` parameter

Please note that a standard "instance" method always must have `self` as a first argument. This is a python specific. In the real world Python will (of course!) store your method only once in memory, even if you instantiate thousands of objects of your class. Consider this an optimization. If you then invoke your method on one of your thousands of instances, always the same single piece of code is called. But for it to distinguish on which particular object the code of the method should work on your instance is passed to this internally stored piece of code as the very first argument. This is the `self` argument. It is some kind of implicit argument and always needed for regular (instance) methods. (Not: static methods - there you *don't* need an instance to invoke them).

As this argument is implicit and always needed most programming languages **hide** it to the programmer (and handle this internally - under the hood - in the correct way). It does not really make much sense to expose this special argument anyway.

Unfortunately Python does not follow this principle. Python does not hide this argument which is implicitly required. (Python's incorporation of OOP concepts is a bit ... simple.) Therefore you see `self` almost everywhere in methods. In your mind you can ignore it, but you need to write it explicitly if you define your own classes. (Which is something you should do in order to structure your programs in a good way.)

### The static method `__new__()`

Python is quite special. While regular programming languages follow a strict and immutable concept of how to create instances of particular classes, Python is a bit different here. This behavior can be changed. This behavior is implemented in `__new__()`. So if you do this ...

```py
myObj = FooBar()
```

... Python implicitly invokes `FooBar.__new__()` which in turn invokes a constructor-like (instance) method named `__init__()` that you could (!) define in your class (as an instance method) and *then* returns the fully initialized instance. This instance is then what is stored in `myObj` in this example her.

You could modify this behavior if you want. But this would requires a very very very particularly unusual use case. You will likely never have anything to do with `__new__()` itself in your entire work with Python. My advice: If you're somehow new to Python just ignore it.

Comment: Note that a `staticmethod` can be invoked either way, on an instance and on a class. It simply receives neither as a first argument. In fact, any method can be invoked either way, but you have to manually pass the right first argument if you’re using it in an “unusual” way.

Comment: @deceze: That's true. But I recommend against this as it violates a clean approach to OOP concepts. Just because Python allows you to do specific things it does not mean you really should do these things. A script/programming languages is nothing more than a toolbox. It's up to you to decide which tools make sense and which don't. Most of the time all tools are carefully defined and make *much* sense. In Python it's a bit different: Sometimes some tools don't make much sense and some tools are even missing completely ...

Comment: Sure, but one example of this "call it anyway you want" is: `lst.sort(key=str.upper)`. You're providing a method of the `str` class which is nominally an instance method but used without an instance here, but by virtue of how `sort` will invoke it, it will act as if called on that instance. So it's very useful to understand how these things *actually* work in Python instead of keeping it abstractly OOP.

Comment: That's an interesting application, indeed. But that's somehow my point: This (mis)uses an instance method as a static method. This I would consider as a "hack": Deviate from clear concepts in order to gain little advantage. A (conceptually) more cleaner approach would be a lambda expression.

Comment: You can call it a "hack" all you want, it's the practical application of how Python is implemented. I'd count something like `reduce(operator.add, foo)` in the same category. Sure, you could very explicitly write `lambda x, y: x + y` or `lambda x, y: operator.add(x, y)`, but that's really repetitive, verbose and unnecessary…

Comment: Yes, but that really depends on the point of view: From a conceptual view point static methods and regular instance methods should be two completely different things. That why these kind of "hacks" are not possible in other programing languages.

Comment: Tell that to things like the idiomatic Javascript `Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes)`… Every language has things that "shouldn't work" according to some concept but do work due to the specifics of the language. Python isn't only OOP; OOP is just *one* of its paradigms. I'd compare that to the SQL language… there's a specific standardised subset of SQL that works on any SQL compliant database, but in practice you'll be using database-specific language extensions all the time.

Comment: FWIW, [the official Python documentation itself condones things like `key=str.upper`.](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto)