# Am I using static method correctly?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I have a large class that looks like the following:

```py
class Trainer:
    def __init__(self, name, age, height, weight):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
    
    def fit(self, dataloader):
        ....DO MODEL TRAINING...
        
        self.save(path=xxx)
        self.load(path=xxx)
    
    def save(self, path):
        self.model.eval()
        torch.save(self.model.state_dict(), path)
    
    @staticmethod
    def load(path: str):
        """Load a model checkpoint from the given path."""
        checkpoint = torch.load(path, map_location=torch.device("cpu"))
        return checkpoint
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438473/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-static-methods), I see that since my `load()` does not need self since in the `load` method, we do not call self, then we should use `staticmethod`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use static method here. To use static method we don't need to pass class instance, `self` argument to work upon. Static methods are like , they are just independent of class's instance. And they can be called directly via `Class_name.static_method_name` without creating the instance to access the method.

Some more readings [here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/staticmethod.html)