# TypeError: B2() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)...Why does it matter if the function is called exactly as named or with a variable

Tags: python

Having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around this one. I'm sure the answer is simple but its been driving me batty.

In the following code:

```
class f1():
    valnum=1

    def A1(self):
        self.valnum=5
        print self.valnum

    def B2(self):
        self.valnum=10
        print self.valnum


    funlist=[A1,B2]


x=f1
x()

x().A1()
x().funlist[1]()
```

`A1()` will execute as expected but not `B2()`. Ultimately, I want to have the code call a random function from the list, but the `TypeError: B2() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)` keeps getting in my way. Why is this and what's the best solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x().funlist[1]()` isn't doing quite what you think it is.

`funlist` is a class attribute. It contains references to the instance methods `A1` and `B1`, but doesn't actually associate them with any instance - they are known as **unbound** methods.

When you call that code, you're presumably trying to say "call the first function in `funlist` on the instance `x`". But what it's *actually* doing is "call the function referenced in the class attribute `funlist` associated with the class of `x`", which isn't the same thing at all.

Now, Python doesn't actually make much of a distinction in practice between bound and unbound methods. You can fake the binding by simply passing the instance in as the first parameter - so this would work:

```
x_instance = x()
x_instance.funlist[1](x_instance)
```

Comment: Actually, `funlist` contains *functions*, not instance methods or unbound methods. Functions don't become unbound methods until they are retrieved off the class object, and when `funlist` is created the class object doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Thanks, that's a useful clarification.

Comment: Alternatively, move the definition of funlist into `__init__` and have it fetch instance methods and be an instance attribute.

Comment: Both this and larsman's answer were great. Between both of them I got everything I needed. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
x().funlist[1]
```

evaluates to the method `B2`, but does not [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static) it to the temporary object `x()` as `x().B2` would do:

```
>>> f1().B2
<bound method f1.B2 of <__main__.f1 instance at 0x1cb4d40>>
>>> f1().funlist[1]
<function B2 at 0x1c3cb90>
```

The solution is to explicitly pass the "`self`" object to the method:

```
obj = f1()
obj.funlist[1](obj)
```