# How to pass member function as argument in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to pass something similar to a member function pointer. I tried the following.

```
class dummy:
    def func1(self,name):
        print 'hello %s' % name
    def func2(self,name):
        print 'hi %s' % name

def greet(f,name):
    d = getSomeDummy()
    d.f(name)

greet(dummy.func1,'Bala')
```

Expected output is `hello Bala`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`dummy.func1` is [unbound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static), and therefore simply takes an explicit `self` argument:

```
def greet(f,name):
    d = dummy()
    f(d, name)

greet(dummy.func1,'Bala')
```

Comment: Thanks. btw, what is unbound method?

Comment: It's a method that has no object associated to it. For more information, refer to [this stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

Answer (score 10):

Since `dummy` is the class name, `dummy.func1` is unbound.

As phihag said, you can create an instance of `dummy` to bind the method:

```
def greet(f,name):
    d = dummy()
    f(d, name)

greet(dummy.func1, 'Bala')
```

Alternatively, you can instantiate `dummy` outside of `greet`:

```
def greet(f,name):
    f(name)

my_dummy = dummy()

greet(my_dummy.func, 'Bala')
```

You could also use `functools.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

def greet(f,name):
    f(name)

my_dummy = dummy()

greet(partial(dummy.func1, my_dummy), 'Bala')
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use something like this:

```
class dummy:
  def func1(self,name):
      print 'hello %s' % name
  def func2(self,name):
      print 'hi %s' % name
def greet(name):
  d = dummy()
  d.func1(name)
greet('Bala')
```

and this works perfectly: [on codepad](http://codepad.org/LrPzpquE)

Comment: Yes this works but what I am trying to do is to pass the member function too as an argument. i.e `greet(dummy.func2,'Bala')` should also work