# Python 2.7 beginner error: unbound method

Tags: python

I've just started learning python and have recently encountered a problem while learning about
classes.
please have a look at the code.

```
class Critter(object):
    """your very own bug generator"""
    total=0
    def status(x):
        print Critter.total
        status=staticmethod(status)
    def __init__(self,name):
        print'a critter has been created'
        self.name=name
        Critter.total+=1


crit1=Critter('pooch')
crit2=Critter('Duff')
crit3=Critter('pluto')

Critter.status()
print'\nAccessing the class attributes through an object:',crit1.total
```

upon running the code I get this error:

```
line 19, in <module>
Critter.status(Critter.total)
TypeError: unbound method status() must be called with Critter instance as first  
argument(got int instance instead)
```

I'm still unclear about how bound/unbound works.  Sorry for the beginner question, any help given would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/242080/understanding-static-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had the following problems:

- indentation issues. Any variables or methods you define that needs to be bound to a class (i.e. belongs to the class) need to be indented one level under the class.
- The `status=staticmethod(status)` needs to be directly defined under the class and not in the scope of the `status()` method's definition. Since `status` refers to `Critter.status()`
- The `status()` method should not be taking any parameter `x` at least based on the `Critter.status()` call you've showed.

The above error you see indicates that python did not recognize the `staticmethod` call in the definition of your class, since its indentation was not correct. So python just defined the `status()` method as a mere instance method (which is the default). For instance methods, python expects the first parameter to be the instance handle.

This should work:

```
class Critter(object):
    """your very own bug generator"""
    total=0

    def status():
        print Critter.total
    status=staticmethod(status)

    def __init__(self,name):
        print 'a critter has been created'
        self.name=name
        Critter.total+=1

crit1=Critter('pooch')
crit2=Critter('Duff')
crit3=Critter('pluto')

Critter.status()
print'\nAccessing the class attributes through an object:',crit1.total
```

**Output:**

```
a critter has been created
a critter has been created
a critter has been created
3

Accessing the class attributes through an object: 3
```

If you're using python > 2.4 (which is likely the case), you can make use of the `@staticmethod` decorator instead to define static methods as follows:

```
class Critter(object):
    """your very own bug generator"""
    total=0

    @staticmethod
    def status():
        print Critter.total

    def __init__(self,name):
        print 'a critter has been created'
        self.name=name
        Critter.total+=1
```

Comment: Ahh i see thank you so much for your help!! i'll post back again to update my progress!!

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your code to:

```
class Critter(object):
    """your very own bug generator"""

    total = 0

    @staticmethod
    def status():
        print Critter.total

    def __init__(self,name):
        print 'a critter has been created'
        self.name = name
        Critter.total += 1
```

To find more on bound and unbound methods try to read this [Class method differences in Python: bound, unbound and static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

Comment: I don't think this is what OP needs.  What is the `status = staticmethod(status)` trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I don't know why someone's downvoting these.  Perhaps they feel like a classmethod would be more appropriate?  but I don't think you can make that judgment here ...

Comment: Thanks for the link! i'm reading up on it now