# class method as a model function for scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

There is a statement in the manual of `curve_fit` that

> The model function, f(x, ...). It must take the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

However, I would like to use as a model function a method of the class which is defined as:

```
def model_fun(self,x,par):
```

So, the first argument is not an independent variable, as you can see. Is there any way how I can use the method of a class as a model function for curve_fit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, create an instance and pass its *bound* method:

```
class MyClass(object):
   ...
   def model_fun(self,x,par): ...

obj = MyClass(...)
curve_fit(obj.model_fun, ...)
```

You can find a good explanation about bound/unbound/etc. in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static).