# What is difference between A.fun and A().fun?

Tags: python

```
class A(object):
    def fun(self):
        pass
ins_a = A.fun
ins_b = A().fun
```

I came across this piece of code and I am unable to understand the difference between the 2 objects.

Comment: `()` makes an instance and calls `fun` on it, the other calls it directly on the class

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class method differences in Python: bound, unbound and static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest difference is if you try to call the methods:
If we add a `print "hello world"`, it will make it more obvious.

```
class A(object):
    def fun(self):
        print ("hello world")

ins_a = A.fun
ins_b = A().fun
```

Now try calling both:

```
In [10]: ins_a()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-52906495cc43> in <module>()
----> 1 ins_a()

TypeError: unbound method fun() must be called with A instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

In [11]: ins_b()
hello world
```

In python 3 they are different types as the unbound method type is gone:

```
In [2]: type(ins_a)
Out[2]: builtins.function

In [3]: type(ins_b)
Out[3]: builtins.method
```

Answer (score 2):

Just try the above code in the interactive interpreter:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def fun(self):
...             pass
... 
>>> ins_a = A.fun
>>> ins_b = A().fun
>>> ins_a
<unbound method A.fun>
>>> ins_b
<bound method A.fun of <__main__.A object at 0x7f694866a6d0>>
```

As you can see, it is a matter of bound/unbound methods. A bound method is a method "tied" to an object. You can have a more thorough explanation [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114267/433940).

Comment: Perhaps it's good to explain the difference between bound and unbound

Comment: Was just trying to find a perfect explanation for this topic as you were posting the comment. Hope it will help the OP :)