# How to import a function in class from another module

Tags: python

```
Module1.py

Class A ():
   def func1(self,...):
      .....


   def func2(self,...):
      .....

Module2.py

   def callfunc():
      How to call func2() from Module1.py
```

In Module2.py, I tried using

```
from Module1 import A

       def callfunc():
          A.func2()
```

but it throws an error stating `TypeError: unbound method **func2()** must be called with **A** instance as first argument (got list instance instead)`

Could someone tell me how to call func2() in Module2.py ?

Answer (score 1):

Your `import` is fine, the problem is that you need an instance of `A` to call the function from

```
def callfunc():
    a = A()
    a.func2()
```

This is because `func2` is [a *bound* method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static), in other words it needs an instance of the class to operate on, hence the `self` argument.

```
def func2(self,...):
```

For you to be able to call it off the class itself, it would be a static function and wouldn't require an instance of the class

```
def func2():
```

Comment: In the end you said instance is not required, then what is the statement i should use ?

Comment: Read more carefully, you **do** need an instance. The last sentence is showing what an **unbound** static function would look like, which is not what your case is.