# What is bound and unbound method in python

Tags: python

what is exactly bound method and unbound method in python. How does it differ when object is created?

i am beginner to python i wrote this small piece of code

```
   class newclass:
      def function1(self,var2):
        self.var2=var2
        print var2
        self.fun_var=var2

   newobject = newclass
   newobject.function1(64)
```

I am getting error like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "basic_class.py", line 8, in <module>
    newobject.function1(64)
TypeError: unbound method function1() must be called with newclass instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
```

what is exactly bound method and unbound method in python

Answer (score 2):

The correct object initialization in Python is:

```
newobject = newclass()   # Note the parens
```

A bound method is an instance method, ie. it works on an `object`. An unbound method is a simple function that can be called without an object context. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114267/2011147) for a detailed discussion.

Note that in Python 3 *unbound method* concept is removed.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you should first create instance of `newclass` and then call function1.

```
class newclass:
  def function1(self,var2):
    self.var2=var2
    print var2
    self.fun_var=var2

newobject = newclass
newobject().function1(64)
```