# Python - Apply member function in a map

Tags: python, dictionary

I declare a class `Employee` and a list consist of it:

```
class Employee():
    def __init__(self, _name):
        self.name = _name
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name

Tom   = Employee("Tom")
Karl  = Employee("Karl")
John  = Employee("John")

employee_list = [Tom, Karl, John]
```

Now I want to have a list of their name by applying `get_name` in a map:

```
name_list = map(get_name, employee_list)


Traceback (most recent call last): File "ask.py", line 13, in <module> 
    name_list = map(get_name, employee_list) 
NameError: name 'get_name' is not defined
```

How could `get_name` be not defined?

How do I do to apply member function in a map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map(get_name, employee_list)`in your code is equivalent to

`[get_name(employee) for employee in employee_list]`

not `[employee.get_name() for employee in employee_list]`

You should declare a `get_name` method outside of `Employee` class:

```
def get_name(employee):
    return employee.name
```

or an easier way with `Lambda`:

`name_list = map(lambda employee: employee.name, employee_list)`

Comment: there's a typo at `[employee.get_name()] for employee in employee_list]`: the `]` after get_name()

Comment: this was not the question asked

Answer (score 2):

You have to call the method from the instance. You can use a lambda for this

```
name_list = map(lambda e: e.get_name(), employee_list)
```

Comment: `e.get_name()`, not `e.get_name`.

Answer (score 2):

This should be done using a list comprehension:

```
names = [employee.get_name() for employee in employee_list]
```

---

Additionally, I would suggest you to shorten the way you create the employee_list as well by not assigning intermediate variable names, but directly creating the instances inside the list literal:

```
employee_list = [Employee("Tom"), Employee("Karl"), Employee("John")]
```

This could be further shortened by using a list comprehension again:

```
employee_list = [Employee(name) for name in ("Tom", "Karl", "John")]
```

Answer (score 2):

While all other answers are correct, all miss one particular feature of python: "instance method" can be called in a "class method" manner, passing class instance as a first parameter. So (at least in python2.7), the following works just fine:

```
map(Employee.get_name, employee_list)
```

Refer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static) for some details on why and how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Colleagues, thank you for the discussion, it helped me. I only want to note that `map` creates an <strike>generator</strike> iterator, not a list. So, an <strike>complete</strike> analogue is

```
(get_name(employee) for employee in employee_list)
```

instead of

```
[get_name(employee) for employee in employee_list]
```

For example, this is essential when you do not want (cannot) keep all data in memory:

```
for L in map(str.strip,open("huge_file")):
    do_something(L)
```

Comment: To be pedantic, `map` creates a `map` object, which is an *iterator* but not a generator (although for most cases the distinction is irrelevant)

Answer (score 0):

`map` calls a function, but `get_name()` is a method. If you really want to use `map` then you can take advantage of the way that Python implements methods: they are equivalent to calling the function as an unbound method with the object as the first `self` argument:

```
name_list = map(Employee.get_name, employee_list)
```

To access the method without binding it to a specific instance you need to access through on the class. Note that this won't work correctly if you have a variety of subclasses of Employee and `get_name` is overridden.

The more Pythonic way is, as others have said, to use a list comprehension, but if you want to go 'Pythonic' then you shouldn't be using an accessor method at all: you should just be accessing the `name` attribute for a simple value like this, or turn it into a property if you need more complex access:

```
names = [employee.name for employee in employee_list]
```