# How to call a method of an object given by its name as string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, reflection, python-3.6

I have a python3 object (class instance), generated by an

```
myObj = myClass()
```

line. I have also a `myMethodName` string:

```
myMethodName = "exampleName"
```

. How can I call a method of `myObj` named by `myMethodName`? Thus, in this case, I want to call `myObj.exampleName`, which is coming from like a `getAttr(myObj, myMethodName)`.

Unfortunately, a naive solution refered by the python docs (for example, [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr)) gives my only a `KeyError` or `AttributeError`.

This fails on that myObj doesn't have a `method` method:

```
method = getAttr(myObj, myMethodName)
myObj.method(param)
```

This fails on that `myMethodName` has more of fewer arguments:

```
method = getAttr(myObj, myMethodName)
method(myObj, param)
```

Calling simply

```
method = getAttr(myObj, myMethodName)
method(param)
```

which would be the most logical, gives

```
TypeError: exampleName() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

So, how can I do this?

I use python 3.6, if it matters.

---

Extension: here is an MCVE:

```
class Test:
  name = None
  def __init__(name):
    self.name = name
  def process():
    method = getattr(self, 'process_' + name)
    method("param")
  def process_test(param):
    print ("process_test(): "+param)

test = Test("cica")
test.process("test")
```

Comment: Your `method` already is the method, can't you just call it like `method(params)`? I'd test it myself if you had provided an MCVE...

Comment: @StefanPochmann Also this gives an error. I extended it into the question.

Comment: @StefanPochmann MCVE added.

Comment: That already fails at the **initializer** with `TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Actual working MCVE, please.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Exactly this actually working MCVE what I couldn't produce. The cause of the problem was that I didn't give `self` to the first argument of `process_test()`... It should have been `def process_test(self, param)`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example can be changed for the following:

```
class Test:
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
   def process(self, param):
       method = getattr(self, 'process_' + param)
       method("param")
   def process_test(self, param):
       print ("process_test(): "+param)


test = Test("cica")
test.process("test")
```

I think you are missing the concept of bound/static method in Python. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114267/1388292), it is describing the different types of methods.

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to parametrize the `process_*` functions with `self`...

Answer (score 2):

If the attribute passed to `getattr()` is a method name then it returns a callable which is already bound to the object:

> `getattr(object, name[, default])`
>
> Return the value of the named attribute of object. `name` must be a string. If the string is the name of one of the `object`’s
>   attributes, the result is the value of that attribute. **For example,
>   `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`**. If the named
>   attribute does not exist, `default` is returned if provided, otherwise
>   `AttributeError` is raised.

Proof:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1]
>>> f = getattr(x, 'count') # same as f = x.count
>>> f(1)
4
```

Comment: The result: `TypeError: exampleName() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`. Note: It is not a builtin class, it is a class defined by me.

Comment: @peterh Your problem is that you don't specify the `self` formal argument in your method signatures. [Jacques Gaudin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1388292/jacques-gaudin) fixes that problem.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is caused, because `getattr` returns a method that is already bound to the object instance (`myObj`).

So all you have to do is call your `method` variable as if it was a function.

The second error is probably due to your exampleName not having the same number of parameters as the number of arguments passed to `method`.

All you have to do for the second error is to add the same parameters to the method in the class:

```
myObj = myClass()class myClass:
    def exampleName(self, *args, **keyargs):
        print('Method exampleName was called')

myObj = myClass()

myMethodName = "exampleName"

method = getattr(myObj, myMethodName)
method('some param')
```

Update:

You have some more problems in the example you added:

```
class Test:
    # This was removed, as you already initialize the instance variable in the constructor.
    # Setting it here would cause the variable to be shared by all instances of the class,
    # which you probably do not want, as you are passing the value as argument to the constructor below.
    # name = None

    # You missed to add the self parameter
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    # Again, self parameter was missed
    # Additionally, we added a `suffix` parameter, that will accept the `test` value from the `process` call
    # We also added *args and **keyargs that will accept arbitrary number of parameters. Those will be
    # passed down to the `process_test` method.
    def process(self, suffix, *args, **keyargs):
        # We use the `suffix` parameter here, (instead of `name`)
        method = getattr(self, 'process_' + suffix)
        method(*args, **keyargs)

    def process_test(self, param):
        print("process_test(): " + param)


test = Test("cica")
test.process("test", "some param")
```

Comment: Minor format fix, I hope it is okay. Now I am testing.

Comment: I see you reverted it, are you sure it is correct syntax?

Comment: Thanks! Solution found, it was a trivial problem.