# Handling apply function in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

consider a dataframe:

```
x = pd.DataFrame({'a' :[1,2,3], 'b':['za','zb','zc']})
```

when I tried

```
x['b'].apply(str.upper)
```

it is working fine.

but when i tried

```
x['b'].apply(str.replace('z',''))
```

it is throwing an error.

Can any one help me what are the functions we can use inside apply and map functions in pandas

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what is actually causing your error: you can use any function within `apply`, but `str.replace('z', '')` is not a valid statement. This will throw an error on its own.

`replace` is a [bound method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static) for string objects. It is meant to be called on a string object, not on the string type:

```
'xyz'.replace('z', '')    # Returns 'xy'
str.replace('z', '')      # Throws TypeError (not enough arguments)
```

Neither of the above statements return a function, so the result cannot be used with `apply`. As in the answer by @jezrael, to use `replace` with `apply`, you need a function which takes one argument, such as a lambda.

The reason `str.upper` works, despite also being a bound method, is that it does not take any other arguments, and therefore can be called with one argument. So `str.upper('xyz')` is equivalent to the proper usage `'xyz'.upper()`. You would see the same error as with your use of `replace` if you tried `x['b'].apply(str.upper())`

Answer (score 1):

In pandas is better use `str` accessor [functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html):

```
print(x['b'].str.upper())
0    ZA
1    ZB
2    ZC
Name: b, dtype: object

print(x['b'].str.replace('z',''))
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: b, dtype: object
```

But if need `apply` add `lambda`, but it failed if some `NaN`s values:

```
print(x['b'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('z','')))
0    a
1    b
2    c
Name: b, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thats fine bro. but I want to know why we can't use that inside apply. Else tell me what kind of functions we can use inside apply.

Comment: The reason is because you need to call `str.replace` with its arguments at the time you apply it, not at the time you pass it to apply. You can use a `lambda` as @jezrael suggested or you can use `functools.partial`

Comment: @Imran - Thank you.

Comment: @Saravanan - In my opinion generally in `apply` with one column (Series) is possible use functions working elementwise, but in pandas is always better first use vectorized functions and then loops (apply under the hood are loops), Jeff, one of dev of pandas now, it describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002)

Comment: Thank you @jezrael