# python - function became "unbound method". why?

Tags: python

I want to create a python class to encapsulate some global variables:

```
class TestEnvironment(object):
    _on_out = None
    # ...

    @staticmethod
    def onOut():
        return TestEnvironment._on_out

    @staticmethod
    def setOnOut(on_out):
        TestEnvironment._on_out = on_out

# -------------------------------------------------------------------- #

def log(msg, process = None):
    print msg

# -------------------------------------------------------------------- #

if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestEnvironment.setOnOut(log)
    print log
    print TestEnvironment.onOut()    
    TestEnvironment.onOut()("A test")
```

When running I get:

```
<function log at 0x7fd7738122a8>
<unbound method TestEnvironment.log>
...
TypeError: unbound method log() must be called with TestEnvironment instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Seems that when I set `log` into `TestEnvironment` it became unbound method.

How can I overpass it?

Comment: This only happens in Python 2; you should really upgrade.

Comment: Try the @staticmethod decorator for `log` too?

Comment: In a nutshell: because of how class properties are returned via `__get__` according to the descriptor protocol: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html

Comment: Note that this wouldn't happen if you created a `TestEnvironment` instance and converted `setOnOut` to be a normal instance method.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

Removed my answer is it is no longer relevant (question seem to have changed). 
Either way - running your code on Python 3.6 seem to work:

```
Python 3.6.1 (default, Dec 2015, 13:05:11)
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

<function log at 0x7f2787e0a488>
<function log at 0x7f2787e0a488>
A test
```

Here is a way to get it to work in Python 2.7:

```
def onOut():
    return TestEnvironment.__dict__['_on_out']
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. `log ` is a free function, not a class method. How can it be declared @staticmethod?

Comment: Not sure, I think when I saw this question initially the block was indented and part of the class / or your code was somehow different.
I agree it doesn't seem right now.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: @EladWeiss - see solution using `__dict__`