# How the scoping works in python?

Tags: python

I am new to object oriented world and trying following code in python and calling function of one class from another class.

**Mycode.py**

```
class A:

def funcA():
    return "sometext"

def funcB(self):
    self.funcA()  # calls func A internally from funcB
```

**secondcode.py**

```
from Mycode import A

class B:
      def funcC(self):
          A.funcB(self)  # it gives error for call funcA() as it is unknown to class B
if __name__ == '__main__':

b=B()
b.funcC()
```

AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'funcA' How does scoping work with respect to classes in python?

Comment: Could you fix the indentation here so that it's identical to the files on your computer?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Python. Indention is very important in Python. Please make sure your indention is correct before submitting your question.

Comment: Also I believe  there is an error in `def func C(self): ` line. Please fix it so that your code is syntatically correct and well indented.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not scope, but you have misunderstanding on `self`.

```
class B:
      def func C(self):
          A.funcB(self)
```

In the above code, `self` is an instance of `B` instead of `A`. But `A.funcB` should accept an instance of `A`. Or `self.funcA` in `A.funcB` is unavaliable.

Comment: I think the problem is about understanding of [bound and unbound functions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

Comment: I am new can someone fix the issue here so that i can call funcB from using A.funcB which should call internally funcA internally?

Comment: @running.t I somehow disagree. Because many new comers think that `self` is a key word or let's say magic word like `this` in Java. But actually it isn't. It is just a normal variable. It can be whatever you want. It can be `def funcC(hahah):`. And if you use `hahah` as `self`, it can still work.

Comment: Still i could not understand. Pls help me in fixing my code.

Comment: @Manish It's hard to fix in this structure. Basically you need at least an instance of `A`. like `a = A() a.funcB()`.