# Why does setting a method in a python class does not pass self when called?

Tags: python, python-object

If I write this:

```
class A:
    def a(self):
        return 2
    def b(self):
        print(self.a())

e = A()

def xa(self):
    return 3 

e.a = xa
e.b()
```

will explode saying that:

```
TypeError: xa() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

why does this happen? (if xa has no arguments then it works, printing 3, but then I can't access self).

This is for testing purposes, not actual production code

Comment: `self` is just a name. You can write `mickeyMouse` instead of `self` and everything works the same. If you want to define an instance method instead of an instance attribute that happens to be a callable you want to set the attribute on the class.

Comment: Good explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/114267/1916917)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`e.a = xa` doesn't make `xa` a bound instance method (which would implicitly pass `self`), it's just some random function stored as an instance attribute.

If you want it to act like a bound method, you have two options:

1. Attach it to the class, e.g. `A.a = xa` (but that modifies the class itself, including all instances). This doesn't bind it on its own, but it will invoke the descriptor protocol when `e.a` is looked up, which triggers implicit binding.
2. Manually bind it to the instance [with `types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.MethodType), by adding `import types` to the top of your file, and changing the assignment to:

   ```
   e.a = types.MethodType(xa, e)  # First argument is function to bind, second is instance to bind to
   ```

Comment: Deleted my answer because yours was both faster and better, +1