# Difference between Bound methods and instance methods in python

Tags: python, methods

I am a begineer in python and sorry if it sound like a newbie question, but i am really confused about the differences between the two. Can someone please explain this with examples, it would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bound method is an instance method which has been bound to the instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Class method differences in Python: bound, unbound and static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

Answer (score 1):

By default, all methods you create are instance methods.
For instance, here `distance_to_origin` is an instance method of class `Point`:

```py
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  def distance_to_origin(self):
    return (self.x**2 + self.y**2)**0.5
```

`Point.distance_to_origin` is just a function that takes one argument and does some computation on it.

```
>>> Point.distance_to_origin
<function Point.distance_to_origin at 0x7f2cd4610a60>
```

As juanpa.arrivillaga said in the comment, a *bound* method is an instance method *bound* to an instance.

```py
>>> p = Point(3, 4)
>>> p.distance_to_origin
<bound method Point.distance_to_origin of <__main__.Point object at 0x7f2cd3f5aba8>>
>>> p.distance_to_origin()
5.0
```

You can think of it as a partially applied function, where the object to which the method was bound will be assigned to `self`.

```
>>> f = p.distance_to_origin
>>> f()
5.0
```

Apart from instance methods, there are also class methods and static methods. Class methods act on classes, and static methods act neither on classes nor on instances of classes.

```py
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

  @classmethod
  def from_polar(cls, r, theta):
    x = r * cos(theta)
    y = r * sin(theta)
    return cls(x, y)

  @staticmethod
  def from_polar(r, theta):
    x = r * cos(theta)
    y = r * sin(theta)
    return Point(x, y)
```

You can read about them here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/

Comment: Thank you so much sir, this is really helpful!