# Not able to call a function using the python inheritance?

Tags: python, inheritance

I am new to python, please help me with the below question-

Question: You have already given a class `base`, now you have to declare a class called `code` which inherits the class `base` and calls the `hello` of the `base` class.

Example:

- Input: `4`
- Output: `["Hello Python", "Hello Python", "Hello Python", "Hello Python"]`

```py
class base:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n=n
    def hello(n):
        return ["Hello Python" for i in range(n)]
```

I tried as below:

```py
class code(base):
    def __init__(self):
        base.__init__(self,5)
x=code()
x.hello()
```

but got error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-1a7429b02c84> in <module>
     12         base.__init__(self,5)
     13 x=code()
---> 14 x.hello()

<ipython-input-88-1a7429b02c84> in hello(n)
      3      self.n=n
      4     def hello(n):
----> 5         return ["Hello Python" for i in range(n)]
      6 
      7 

TypeError: 'code' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: `def hello(self,n):`

Comment: @Dolendra Ningthemcha are you able to change the `base` class?

Comment: If it wasn't clear, `def hello(n)` is non-standard and arguably wrong. If it's supposed to be a bound method, it should take `self` as a parameter. If it's supposed to be an unbound method, it should be decorated with `@staticmethod`.

Answer (score 0):

**About the error:**

`base.hello` is **unbound** method.

`x.hello()` is translated to `code.hello(x)` and `range` function takes in int type variables.
This makes it clear why it is giving `TypeError: 'code' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Now for solution

**There are two ways to make this work**

1)So to make this work without changing `base` class:

```py
class code(base):
    def __init__(self):
        base.__init__(self,5)
x = code()
code.hello(x.n)
```

2) Or change the method type(bound method):

```py
class base:
    def __init__(self,n):
        self.n=n
    def hello(self):
        return ["Hello Python" for i in range(self.n)]
```

For more clarity on bound, unbound, static methods [Bound, unbound and static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114214/class-method-differences-in-python-bound-unbound-and-static)

For more on `class, static, instance` methods, refer to [Python method types in classes](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)